# How to deploy a Java EE application in the Amazon cloud?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, amazon-ec2, cloud, cloud-hosting

Here's the thing: I need to take a certain Java EE web app and deploy it to Amazon EC2 (which I will need to setup first) starting next month (using the http://aws.amazon.com/free/faqs/ AWS Free Tier Usage - hope it supports Tomcat + MySQL/PostgreSQL).

The problem: I have never ever deployed a Java EE app (not even a *normal* one on a dedicated hosting) nor have I setup an Amazon EC2 enviorment.

Are there any, idiot proof preferably, tutorials/how-to's/whatever on doing it from the very beginning (signing up to Amazon) till the very end (when your app is all up and running)?

I did find some tutorials on how to setup an Amazon EC2 instance, how to normally deploy a Java EE app but what I'm looking for is a single tutorial putting it all together.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Start with an [Ubuntu AMI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide). Then [install tomcat](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-install-tomcat-in-ubuntu/). Now put the WAR file of your J2EE app where tomcat can see it. You can use the [AWS console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) to start/stop your machines, configure firewall rules that allow you to access port 80, etc. There won't be a step by step guide telling you exactly what to do, welcome to being a programmer.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully there's always SO.

Answer (score 7):

Once we have the instance (like Ubuntu) running http://youtu.be/hJRSti6DsJg then, installs Glassfish (Java EE server) and configure it to work with Java EE. It depends more of the instance itself (Ubuntu) than EC2 Amazon... here a nice video (how to install Glashfish in Ubuntu + Netbeans config) http://youtu.be/CKuoDm6bqRM

Note:

- Keep in mind both videos are a little old (may some adjustments are necessary)
- The videos are indirectly related. But my point is: there isn't much info about Amazon AWS and Java EE, but there are a lot info about Amazon AWS and Linux, and Linux and Java EE.

**Update**
You can try Amazon Beanstalk (Deployment & Management) integrated with Netbeans (without Glashfish?) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.html

[SSH to Elastic Beanstalk instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742478/ssh-to-elastic-beanstalk-instance)

http://aws.amazon.com/java/ (Amazon + Java)

[image]

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk is the way to go. Here's another SO thread with some info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902698/how-to-deploy-a-java-webapp-on-amazon-ec2-so-that-you-can-efficiently-use-autosc/28023413#28023413

Answer (score 2):

[Boxfuse](https://boxfuse.com) now supports deploying Java EE applications using either Tomcat, TomEE Web Profile or TomEE Plus to AWS with a single command

```
boxfuse run mytomeeapp-1.0.war -env=prod
```

This will create an image, provision all necessary AWS infrastructure (AMIs, security groups, auto-scaling groups, launch configurations, ELBs, Elastic IPs, ...) and launch the instances. It supports blue/green zero downtime updates with Elastic IPs and ELBs.

You can find a tutorial here: https://boxfuse.com/blog/javaee-aws

*Disclaimer: I am the founder and CEO of Boxfuse*