# How to force https on elastic beanstalk?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can't seem to force https on the free usage tier of elastic beanstalk.

I have tried the following suggestion at [How to force https on amazon elastic beanstalk without failing the health check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858492/how-to-force-https-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-without-failing-the-health-check)

Using this Apache rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/status$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/version$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_hostmanager/ 
RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

When I try that, http requests do not get redirected to https as I would like. Instead, the http page loads normally. I've also tried to use the X-Forwarded-Port header with the same result.

I've also tried the following rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

And this rule causes a redirect loop. So it would seem that the apache rewrite rules don't pick up the Elastic Load Balancer headers X-Forwarded-Port and  X-Forwarded-Proto, but also a redirect loop isn't what I am going for either.

Please help. I am new to AWS, Elastic Beanstalk, and not very familiar with Apache rules. I am not too sure where to go from here. Thanks.

Comment: After sleeping on it, it appears the rewrite rules now detect the X-Forwarded-Proto header. Not entirely sure why, but it works now.

Comment: It seems that the Internet cannot agree on a single, complete and working solution to this problem. Hopefully you can get some help [here in my post](http://thehunk.blogspot.in/2017/11/how-to-force-redirect-http-to-https-in.html). I had to jump through hoops to come up with this, finally.

Comment: Can anyone know how can I change it to redirect www to non-www

RewriteEngine On
      <If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
      RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
      </If>

Comment: Also see [How can I redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS using an Application Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/) on Amazon's knowledge center. No server config required on the instance.

Answer (score 198):

This answer assumes you have already enabled https in the load balancer security group, added the SSL certificate to the load balancer, have both ports 80 and 443 being forwarded by the load balancer, and pointed your domain name at the Elastic Beanstalk environment with Route 53 (or equivalent DNS service).

## Option 1: Do the redirect with Apache

This is only possible if you are on an Elastic Beanstalk environment that uses Apache (AWS Linux 2 based deployments can be configured to use Apache).  It may not work for a docker-based deployment.

### Amazon Linux 2

Most AWS Linux version 2 based platforms have the option to pick Apache as your proxy host.  This can be done by going to "Configuration" > "Software" >
"Container Options" and setting "Proxy Server" to "Apache", or adding the following to one of your `.config` files in `.ebextensions`:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:
    ProxyServer: apache
```

Having done that, add a configuration file named `.platform/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf` to your codebase ([relevant AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)) with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
<If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</If>
```

### Amazon Linux 1

All you need to do is add the following to one of your [`.config` files in the `.ebextensions` directory of your project](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html):

```
files:
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            RewriteEngine On
            <If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
            RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
            </If>
```

### Explanation

This is moderately straight forward outside of Elastic Beanstalk.  One usually adds an Apache rewrite rule like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Or, if behind a load balancer, like we are in this case:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

However, these configurations only work within a `<VirtualHost>` block.  Changing the `RewriteCond` to an `<If>` block allows it to work properly outside of a `<VirtualHost>` block, allowing us to put in in a standalone Apache config file.  Note that standard Apache setup on CentOS (including the setup on ElasticBeanstalk) inculdes all files matching `/etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf`, which matches the file path where we are storing this file.

The `-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}'` part of the condition prevents it from redirecting if you are not behind a load balancer, allowing you to have shared configuration between a production evironment with a load balancer and https, and a staging environment that is single instance and does not have https.  This is not necessary if you are using load balancers and https on all of your environments, but it doesn't hurt to have it.

## Option 2: Do the redirect with the ALB

This is only possible if you are using an Application Load Balancer.  Amazon has instructions for how to do that here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html

All you need to do is add the following to one of your [`.config` files in the `.ebextensions` directory of your project](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) to replace the http listener with a redirect:

```
Resources:
 AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
  Properties:
    LoadBalancerArn:
      Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancer
    Port: 80
    Protocol: HTTP
    DefaultActions:
      - Type: redirect
        RedirectConfig:
          Host: "#{host}"
          Path: "/#{path}"
          Port: "443"
          Protocol: "HTTPS"
          Query: "#{query}"
          StatusCode: "HTTP_301"
```

## Bad solutions I have seen

I have seen a lot of bad solutions to this problem, and it is worth going through them to understand why this solution is necessary.

1. **Use Cloudfront:**  Some people suggest using non-cached Cloudfront setup in front of Elastic Beanstalk to do the HTTP to HTTPS redirect.  This adds a whole new service (thus adding complexity) that isn't exactly appropriate (Cloudfront is a CDN; it's not the right tool for forcing HTTPS on inherantly dynamic content).  Apache config is the normal solution to this problem and Elastic Beanstalk uses Apache, so that's the way we should go.
2. **SSH into the server and...:** This is completely antithetical to the point of Elastic Beanstalk and has so many problems.  Any new instances created by autoscaling won't have the modified configuration.  Any cloned environments won't have the configuration.  Any number of a reasonable set of environment changes will wipe out the configuration.  This is just such a bad idea.
3. **Overwrite the Apache config with a new file:** This is getting into the right realm of solution but leaves you with a maintenance nightmare if Elastic Beanstalk changes aspects of the server setup (which they very well may do).  Also see the problems in the next item.
4. **Dynamically edit the Apache config file to add a few lines:** This is a decent idea.  The problems with this is that it won't work if Elastic Beanstalk ever changes the name of their default Apache config file, and that this file can get overwritten when you least expect: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=163369

Comment: Stumbled on this in 2021. We successfully did #3 via `.ebextensions`, which worked until we upgraded from PHP7.3 to PHP7.4 environment. The default EB environment for PHP7.4 is Nginx, so we didn't realise our HTTP->HTTPS redirect stopped working.

Comment: @haz Which webserver gets used (Nginx or Apache) is configurable on Amazon Linux 2 based environments

Comment: ahh thank you!!  I just used your code for ALB and it worked--my EB had nginx, but it looks like you can switch to apache (was going to try that and option 1 if option 2 didn't work).  I've been neck deep in AWS' docs and tried their suggested file earlier but it didn't work for some reason and this did https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/resource-configuration/alb-http-to-https-redirection-full.config

Answer (score 16):

> **EDIT: While I love this answer, it is now *very old*.** AWS has come up with new services (like [Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager)) that make part of this answer obsolete. Additionally, using the `.ebextensions` folder with Apache is a cleaner way to handle this redirect as explained above.

If you are hosting your website on S3, parts of this answer may still be useful to you.

---

This worked for me:

1. Upload the certificate to AWS using the [`aws`](http://aws.amazon.com/cli) console command. The command structure is:

   ```
   aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name CERTIFICATE_NAME --certificate-body "file://PATH_TO_CERTIFICATE.crt" --private-key "file://YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY.pem" --certificate-chain "file://YOUR_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN.ca-bundle" --path /cloudfront/
   ```
2. In your Elastic Beanstalk application, go to **Configuration** -> **Network Tier** -> **Load Balancing** and click the **gear icon**.
3. Select **Secure listener port** as **443**. Select **Protocol** as **HTTPS**. Select the `CERTIFICATE_NAME` from **step 2** for **SSL certificate ID**. Save the configuration.
4. Go to your **Console**. Click **EC2 Instances**. Click **Load Balancers**. Click through the load balancers. Click **Instances** and scroll down to see the EC2 instances assigned to that load balancer. If the EC2 instance has the same name as your Application URL (or something close), take note of the **DNS Name** for the load balancer. It should be in the format `awseb-e-...`
5. Go back to your **Console**. Click **CloudFront**. Click **Create Distribution**. Select a **Web** distribution.
6. Set up the distribution. Set your **Origin Domain Name** to the load balancer DNS name you found in **step 5**. Set the **Viewer Protocol Policy** to **Redirect HTTP to HTTPS**. Set **Forward Query Strings** to **Yes**.   Set **Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)** to the URL(s) you want to use for your application. Set **SSL Certificate** to the `CERTIFICATE_NAME` you uploaded in **step 2**. Create your distribution.
7. Click on your distribution name in CloudFront. Click **Origins**, select your origin, and click **Edit**. Ensure your **Origin Protocol Policy** is **Match Viewer**. Go back. Click **Behaviors**, select your origin, and click **Edit**. Change **Forward Headers** to **Whitelist** and add **Host**. Save.

**Note:** [I wrote a longer guide as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967788/laravel-redirect-all-requests-to-https/29171680#29171680).

Answer (score 10):

With the new Application Load Balancers you can do this fairly trivially now...

Ensure you setup one of these at the time you setup an EB environment (still defaults to classic load balancer I believe). You could not change the type once the environment is created, so recreate it

Once this is done, go to your EC2 settings -> Load Balancers. Click on the load balancer you created for your EB environment. 
You must ensure that you have setup a HTTPS listener prior to this task so make sure you listen on HTTPS 443 with an SSL cert and forward traffic to your instances with HTTP on 80.

Then add a new listener which listens on HTTP and add a default action of "Redirect to:". Make sure you set HTTPS as the protocol, 443 as the port, "Original host, path, query" as the option and finally 301 as the HTTP response code.

Once this listener is added ensure that you update your EC2 Load Balancer security group to accept both HTTPS and HTTP connections, you will see small warning sign on the listener to remind you!

Chris

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work for my www. route but not the naked domain. Any suggestions on why that might be?

Answer (score 6):

The most upvoted doesn't work for me.. the <If> directive only works with Apache 2.4+, but [ElasticBeanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.java) has version 2.2.x.

So, following the same advice as above. Create a file called .ebextensions/https_rewrite.config with the following content

```
files:
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
            RewriteEngine On
            # This will enable the Rewrite capabilities
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
            # This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
            RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

This seems to work for me.

On how to build this file into your WAR file, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423932/where-to-add-ebextensions-in-a-war)

Comment: Additional note about this answer: The <if> block was new in 2.4 and doesn't work in 2.2 which is why you don't see it here.

Comment: EB PHP Solution Stacks now all use Apache 2.4+

Answer (score 4):

Edit: [Zags solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38751749/877676) is more general and correct. I recommend it over mine (which is specific to a python env)

Here's a clean and quick solution that I came up with that avoids hacking wsgi.conf or using CloudFront

In your .ebextensions/some_file.config:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/https_redirect.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      <Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
      RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
      </Directory>
```

I feel like this is too easy, but seems to be working fine.

Also note that I am explicitly redirecting HTTP instead of "not HTTPS".

Comment: So I got this working on one EBS environment. /etc/httpd/conf.d/https_redirect.conf exists and it redirects to https. The problem is on a second environment, setup exactly the same way, the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/https_redirect.conf is NOT there. Any ideas?

Comment: @NitzanWilnai `/etc/httpd/conf.d/https_redirect.conf` doesn't have to exist, see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38751749/1821593)

Comment: Adding a file to /etc/httpd/conf.d was a great idea.  This helped me get to the general solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38751749/2800876)

Answer (score 4):

I am trying to redirect an elastic beanstalk with loadbalancer in 2018. None of the above answers works in my environment. Several issues I encoutered:

1. I was trying the most voted answer, but my tomcat is version 2.7. It does not support .
2. I was using container_commands and copy the 00_applications setting. AWS simply ignores it.

So finally I got it working by reading this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-proxy.html

Here is what I do:

I recreated the folder structure:

```
.ebextensions 
 - httpd
  -conf.d
   -ssl.conf
```

And then this is the content of ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  <Proxy *>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPreserveHost on

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: It redirects to https, but it says server not found. I am using spring MVC web app

Comment: I'm getting a `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "<VirtualHost" ` in the EB logs after adding this. Anyone else seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

It's work for me with the next command:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Port} !=443
```

and without the https check:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
```

It's look like ELB change the value of X-Forwarded-Proto to http (even on TCP protocol).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The headers are documented so you can rely on them. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html

Answer (score 3):

None of the above answers worked for me but some helped me to figure out the answer that worked for me
Also I found the below url which helped
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html

I created the file structure mentioned in above url to change 2 files
httpd.conf
00_application.conf

copy the whole httpd.conf from your instance and put it in your code under .ebextention under the folder structure mentioned in the above link. Then just add below line to that file in your project

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Do that same for 00_application.conf, copy it from your instance and place it in your codebase under .ebextention under httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf
Now edit this file and add the below between VirtualHost

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Now deploy your code
It should work.

Answer (score 2):

I had a difficult time figuring this out so after I came up with a solution I [wrote a detailed explanation of my solution](http://mattsommer.io/spring-eb-apache-https-redirect) to hopefully help someone else. This is specific to Tomcat 8, Apache2, and Spring Boot app. There are really useful [ebextension examples in the AWS labs github](https://github.com/awslabs/elastic-beanstalk-docs/tree/master/.ebextensions/aws_provided/security%20configuration).

Summary of what worked for me:

1. Create a file at /src/main/webapp/.ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk.conf
2. Add rewrite conds/rules being careful to include "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so"
3. Deploy to AWS EBS

Here is an [example Spring Boot app](https://github.com/matthewsommer/spring-elasticbeanstalk-loadbalancer-https-redirect).

Answer (score 2):

On elastic beanstalk you can just add your on configuration so that AWS overwrite their, it will allow you to overwrite the web-server configuration and submit your own configuration.

Simply add the following file under the path:  .ebextensions\httpd\conf.d

File content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

   <Proxy *>
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPreserveHost on

   ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log

</VirtualHost>
```

The '.ebextensions' is the standard configuration folder in AWS and the rest just point to which file and folder you wish to overwrite. 
If the file or folder doesn't exist simple create them.

Answer (score 1):

I have following configurations for elastic beanstalk (64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.3.1 running Tomcat 8 Java 8).
I created a directory .ebextensions and added a .config YAML file with the rewrite conditions

Zagas [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38751749) described above (which is very complex) doesn't work for me.

1. Because "If" condition is unknown
2. Because of Apache 2.2 I don't have mod_rewrite.so included in my httpd.conf file

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40670047) make more sense for me, but also this doesn't work. Nothing happens, and I cannot see file "ssl_rewrite.conf" under "conf.d" directory.

Third tried solution was to add "run.config" and "ssl_rewrite.conf" files under ".ebextendsion" directory.

run_config contains

```
container_commands:
copy-config:
command: "cp .ebextensions/ssl_rewrite.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d"
```

ssl_rewrite.conf contains

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

ssl_rewrite.conf is created under "conf.d" direcotry but redirect from http to https doesn't work.

The only worked solution for me was to add the following lines in "/etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
......
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
......
</VirtualHost>
```

but this is a temporary solution and if a machine is replaced my https redirection is gone.

Comment: _"if a machine is replaced my https redirection is gone"_ I think you could use the same trick shown in Zags' answer to write the file automatically when ELB deploys the application in a new instance. Basically, give your file path under `files:`, the file content under `content: |` and set the appropriate mode, owner and group. ELB will then create the file for you, automatically.

Comment: I have used the above method (in my comment) to deploy this file as part of application (instead of writing it directly into the current instance). I checked through SSH that the file exists. However, it also didn't work for me, despite my setup being very close to yours: _64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.1 running Tomcat 8 Java 8_ One thing though, the file didn't exist at all originally - it was created new. Should I be editing `/etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk.conf` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody is still struggling:

I've struggled for some time and finally, I've found a GitHub (from AWS team) with all AWS configs and the example below works for the HTTP>HTTPS redirection for Apache 2.2.  (For configs for Apache 2.4 and Nginx please see the link below).

**Apache 2.2**

1. Create a file in the root directory of your app:
   **YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT/.ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk.conf**
   (In case of using IntelliJ / Java make sure it go added to the final .WAR artifact)
2. Add the following lines to enable the redirection in the virtual host:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker
       RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

       <Proxy *>
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
       </Proxy>

       ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
       ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
       ProxyPreserveHost on

       ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

For more examples for Apache 2.4 and Nginx please visit this GitHub repository:

https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/tree/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/java-tomcat

Also, there is plenty more useful configuration and examples available.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

## Enabling HTTPS through an environment variable

I needed to enforce HTTPS only for our production environment, and not for the development and staging ones which are also on Elastic Beanstalk but do not use a load balancer (and therefore cannot be assigned a certificate directly).

I use an environment variable `USE_HTTPS`. We copy the the `ssl_rewrite.conf` file if and only if `USE_HTTPS` is set to `true`.

**.ebextensions/files/ssl_rewrite.conf**

```
RewriteEngine On
<If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</If>
```

**.ebextensions/https.config**

```
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/https_setup.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash

      echo "USE_HTTPS env var: ${USE_HTTPS,,}"
      outfile=/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf
      if [ "${USE_HTTPS,,}" == "true" ]; then
        echo "Configure SSL rewrite"
        cp .ebextensions/files/ssl_rewrite.conf $outfile
        chmod 644 $outfile
        chown root:root $outfile
      else
        [ -f $outfile ] && rm $outfile
        echo "Do not use SSL"
        exit 0
      fi

container_commands:
  01_https_setup:
    command: "/home/ec2-user/https_setup.sh"
```

Note that if you change `USE_HTTPS`, you need to redeploy your application for the change to take effect. You can also remove the `echo` commands in the `https.config` file if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

AWS has also some [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html) on this.

If you're using an application load balancer, add the file `http-to-https.config` to your `.ebextensions` folder and then add the following config (**Don't forget to put in the ARN of your https certificate**):

*NOTE: Please be sure that you haven't yet added a listener on port 443 via the EB console. If you did so, delete the listener before adding the .config file.*

```
Resources:
  AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: redirect
          RedirectConfig:
            Protocol: HTTPS
            Port: '443'
            Host: '#{host}'
            Path: '/#{path}'
            Query: '#{query}'
            StatusCode: HTTP_301
      LoadBalancerArn:
        Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
  AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListenerHTTPS:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'
    Properties:
      Certificates:
        - CertificateArn: Replace with Certificate ARN
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn:
            Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancerTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn:
        Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancer
      Port: 443
      Protocol: HTTPS
```

The advantage of using your LB for this is that your config will be agnostic to the server you use like nginx, apache, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer from [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=61851) to be helpful.

All I did was make the health check path `/index.php` instead of `/` in the application load balancer default process.

Answer (score 1):

All of the above answers are outdated in 2022, since AWS made silent changes to ElasticBeanstalk without updating the documentation properly.

However it has become very simple to do it from the AWS console when using a load balancer. You just need to disable the listener on the 80 port (http) once you created the https listener (environment -> configuration -> load balancer). And that's it.[image: disable http]

No more problem with health checks since they are performed directly on the instance, not on the load balancer.

Comment: This does not force https or redirect http request to https, it just stops listening at that port (http no longer works)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply put an .htaccess file in the root folder? That way you can simply test and debug it. And if you include it in the .zip, it will automatically deployed on all instances again.

Simply use `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the most voted answer is a bit old now.
The answer by A Paul is actually the correct answer. The link provided in his answer is by AWS (so it is the recommended method to override your Apache configuration to make the redirection from HTTP to HTTPS when running your application on Elastic Beanstalk).

There is one very important thing to note. If you are deploying more than 1 web app, then adding the .ebextensions folder inside one of your web app is not going to work. You will notice that Non of the configurations you specified are being written or created. If you are deploying multiple Web Apps on Elastic Beanstalk environment, then you will need to read this article by AWS
[Java Tomcat Deploy Multiple WAR files on Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-multiple-war-files.html)

In general, you will need to have the following structure before you issue the eb command on it to deploy the WAR files:

```
MyApplication.zip
├── .ebextensions
├── foo.war
├── bar.war
└── ROOT.war
```

if .ebextentions folder exists inside each WAR file, then you will notice that it is completely ignored and no configuration changes will be performed.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

We have solved it on our backend by handling `X-Forwarded-Proto` properly.

This is our Grails config but it will help you with the idea:

```
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = true
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 80
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 443
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderName = 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderValue = 'http'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderName = 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderValue = 'https'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
        [pattern: '/**', access: 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL']
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend another two answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/43026082/8775205, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42035023/8775205.
For spring boot users who deploy their services on AWS with ELB, and need step by step guide, you can add an ****.conf file under src/main/webapp/.ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/ in your project.

```
src
--main
----java
----resources
----webapps
------.ebextensions
--------httpd
----------confd
------------****.conf
```

****.conf looks like the following. Noticed that I have my testing site with a single instance, so I add a condition to exclude it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker 
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !testexample.com #excludes test site
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

   <Proxy *>
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPreserveHost on

   ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log

</VirtualHost>
```

After this, remember to add a "resource" under maven-war-plugin in your pom.xml in order to pick up the above configuration.

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>  
     <configuration>  
         <webResources>
             <resource>  
               <!-- some other resource configured by yourself-->
             </resource> 
             <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapps/.ebextensions</directory>
                 <targetPath>.ebextensions</targetPath>
                 <filtering>true</filtering>
             </resource> 
         </webResources>  
     </configuration>  
     <version>2.1.1</version>
 </plugin>
```

Finally commit and push your code, wait AWS codebuild and codepipeline to pick up your code from your repository and deploy to beanstalk environment, or simply pack your project into a war file and upload it to your AWS beanstalk environment

Answer (score 0):

AWS do not accept unserscores (_) in headders, while we can use (-), So Remove underscores from the header variables, example:- **header_var_val = "some value"** replace it with **headervarval = "some value"**. It works for me.

Answer (score -4):

If you use a Load Balanced environment you can follow the instructions for [Configuring HTTPS for your AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html) and at the end disable the HTTP port.

Note that currently the [AWS Free Usage Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free) includes the same amount of hours for an Elastic Load Balancing (ELB) as for an EC2 Micro Instance.

Comment: This way you only enable HTTPS but you don't enforce it. Enforcing means you automatically redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS.

Answer (score -4):

this is an easy solution

1. ssh into your EC2 instance
2. copy the contents of /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf into a local file called wsgi.conf which will be placed in the base folder of your application
3. Edit the local version of wsgi.conf and add the following redirect rules within the < VirtualHost> < /VirtualHost> tags

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
   RewriteRule !/status https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   ```
4. Change the **“/status”** to whatever page you are using as a **health check** page.
5. Save the file
6. Edit your < app>.conf file inside your .**ebextensions** directory to add a container command to copy this version of wsgi.conf over Amazon’s version

   ```
   container_commands:
   01_syncdb:
     command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput" leader_only: true
   02_collectstatic:
     command: "django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput"
   03_wsgireplace:
     command: 'cp wsgi.conf ../wsgi.conf'
   ...
   ```
7. Deploy the code.
8. The deployed version of wsg.conf at /etc/httd/conf.d/wsgi.conf will now include the necessary redirect rules.

It should work and the file will be properly updated for each deployment.  The only thing to watch for is if Amazon changes their base wsgi.conf file contents in the future, then your copy may no longer work.

Autor [rickchristianson](http://rickchristianson.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/updating-wsgi-automatically-in-amazon-aws/)

Comment: Exact duplicate of his own answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858492/how-to-force-https-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-without-failing-the-health-check/21896755#21896755. stop posting duplicate answers!

Comment: the problem can be solved with the same answer ;) its spam ??

Comment: ssh-ing into an instance behind the load balancer and making adjustments defeats the purpose of Elastic Beanstalk. What happens when you scale up and get more instances? Do this on all of them? Manually?

Comment: @fivedogit if you read carefully, you notice that he didn't make adjustments by SSH-ing into the instance. He only SSH to read the file and copy it. After that, he is using `.ebextensions` in his deployment to make the adjustments correctly through Elastic Beanstalk itself, so he's not defeating its purpose.