# Where to add .ebextensions in a WAR?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, war, ebextensions

Scenario:

- AWS Elastic Beanstalk
- Java application
- .ebextensions currently placed in src/main/resources/.ebextensions

Commands are not being executed.

Where is the .ebextensions supposed to go in a Java application?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

.ebextensions should be placed in the root of WAR.

The WAR structure looks like the following:

```
web_app.war
          |
          |_.ebextensions
          |   |_ 01run.config
          |   |_ 02do.config
          |
          |_META-INF
          |
          |_WEB-INF
               |_ classes
               |_ lib
               |_ web.xml
```

Refer to the official AWS [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html) for further information.

Comment: My war is built using maven how would i modify my pom to achieve this

Comment: that's in src/main/webapp

Comment: @GustavoMatias, AWS changed the path of `.ebextensions` for a while, but it accepts both paths(in `/WEB-INF/.ebextensions` and `/.ebextensions` of WAR).

Comment: @GustavoMatias no longer works in sbt version 0.13.6, now using jar uf target/scala-2.10/xxx-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war src/main/webapp/.ebextensions to insert the dir into the WAR file after packaging.

Answer (score 44):

Using Maven I did as follows:

- mkdir src/main/ebextensions
- put .config files into this folder
- add the following to pom.xml

  ```
      <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <webResources>
                  <resource>
                      <directory>src/main/ebextensions</directory>
                      <targetPath>.ebextensions</targetPath>
                      <filtering>true</filtering>
                  </resource>
              </webResources>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  ```

to transfer the files to the top level of the war when it is built.

Comment: As of 2017 this method does not appear to work. The plugin XML does, indeed, add the .ebextensions folder to the top level of the war, but when deployed to a beanstalk, that folder and its contents are nowhere to be found.

Comment: @fivedogit Did you look in the war file? When deployed to EBS, the folder is used up.

Answer (score 11):

Using gradle I did the following

- mkdir src/main/resources/ebextensions
- put .config files into this folder
- add the following to build.gradle

apply plugin: 'war'

```
war {
    from('src/main/resources/ebextensions') {
        into('.ebextensions')
    }
}
```

to transfer the files to the top level of the war when it is built.

Answer (score 1):

you missed resources, it works when I put the path right

```
war {
    from('src/main/resources/ebextensions') {
        into('.ebextensions')
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer seems to place the .ebextensions folder in the root of the classes folder inside the generated JAR, not in the root of it.

Answer (score 1):

Update for people here in 2020, now task name is "bootWar"

```
bootWar {
    from('src/main/resources/ebextensions') {
        into('.ebextensions')
    }
}
```