# Laravel Redirect All Requests To HTTPS

Tags: laravel-4

Our entire site is to be served over https.  I have 'https' in each route.  However, how do I redirect them to https if they attempt it over http?

```
Route::group(array('https'), function()
{
     // all of our routes
}
```

Comment: As many have stated this can be (and IMO should be) done by the web server (NGINX, Apache, etc).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - redirect to HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

**Using App::before**

You might be able to take advantage of the `App::before()` block in the `app/filters.php` file.

Change the block to include a simple check to see if the current request is secure, and if not, redirect it.

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if( ! Request::secure())
    {
        return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
    }
});
```

**Using Filters**

Another option might be to create a filter like so.  People generally store this also in `app/filters.php`.

```
Route::filter('force.ssl', function()
{
    if( ! Request::secure())
    {
        return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
    }

});
```

You can then enforce that new filter to any of your routes, route groups, or controllers like this.

*Individual Route*

```
Route::get('something', ['before' => 'force.ssl'], function()
{
    return "This will be forced SSL";
});
```

*Route Group*

```
Route::group(['before' => 'force.ssl'], function()
{
    // Routes here.
});
```

*Controller*

You'll need to do this in your controller's `__construct()` method.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('force.ssl');
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  I knew there was a way to do it cleanly within Laravel filters.  Cheers

Comment: Use Request::path(), not Request::getRequestUri()

Comment: I was using this method, but it suddenly quit working today after I ran an `apt-get upgrade`. Now I'm getting a routing error: "Call to a member function getAction() on a non-object in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php on line 1528". If I comment out the redirect, it works fine.

Comment: Hats off to a great and comprehensive answer.

Comment: This should not be done in Laravel but should be handled in the .htaccess.  There's no need for the additional overhead of running Laravel to do this.

Comment: Is there an extra square bracket in the code for the route group?

Comment: Do this at the server level not in your application

Comment: For **Laravel 5 and above** check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/28403907/1340784

Comment: The issue I had with this, is that it lost any querystrings (like the GA tracking tags). Here is what I ended up doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967788/laravel-redirect-all-requests-to-https/37128740#37128740

Answer (score 34):

Another answer might be to let your web server handle this.  If you are using Apache, you can use the RedirectSSL feature to make sure all requests are going to the HTTPS version of your site, and if not redirect them.  This will happen before Laravel even get's the request.

[Apache RedirectSSL](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL)

If you're on NGINX, you can accomplish this by having two server blocks.  One for normal HTTPS on port 80, and another for HTTPS on port 443.  Then configure the normal server block to always redirect to ssl version.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    ssl on;
    # other server config stuff here.
}
```

I'd personally go with this option as PHP itself doesn't have to process anything.  It's generally cheaper to process a check like this at the web server level.

Comment: Just to clarify, I consider this answer to be the preferred way of doing things rather than the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, doing it in the application is more time-consuming, because (doing so) the framework is already initialized for each http request, but doing in the server conf is not. I'd use nginx as proxy and X_FORWARDED_PROTO header

Comment: My philosophy: trust the web server redirects, but verify in the application.  This way you get the best of both worlds.  When the web server does it for you, the app experiences no performance hit.  When the web server doesn't (eg, misconfiguration), the app acts as a safety net and the performance hit is *well worth* the tradeoff.

Answer (score 11):

For users using Laravel 4/5 and Elastic Beanstalk, forcing HTTPS is difficult using these methods because the `isSecure()` will return `false`. Further, using `.htaccess` redirects will result in a redirect loop for Chrome and delayed page load times in Firefox.

This set up is for

- Laravel 5 and may work for Laravel 3 / 4
- Application loaded onto Elastic Beanstalk running EC2 server instances
- Route 53 used for DNS resolution
- Cloudfront used for global CDN of all assets and enforcing HTTPS
- I run `aws` on a Windows machine. Linux may vary slightly?

After hours of my own attempts, I managed to get all HTTP requests forwarded to HTTPS using the following steps:

1. Obtain an SSL certificate. Guides and providers are numerous and can be found via a Google search.
2. Upload the certificate to AWS using the [`aws`](http://aws.amazon.com/cli) console command. The command structure is:

   ```
   aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name CERTIFICATE_NAME --certificate-body "file://PATH_TO_CERTIFICATE.crt" --private-key "file://YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY.pem" --certificate-chain "file://YOUR_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN.ca-bundle" --path /cloudfront/
   ```
3. Create an Elastic Beanstalk application. Proceed through the setup process. Once the application is setup, go to **Configuration** -> **Network Tier** -> **Load Balancing** and click the **gear icon**.
4. Select **Secure listener port** as **443**. Select **Protocol** as **HTTPS**. Select the `CERTIFICATE_NAME` from **step 2** for **SSL certificate ID**. Save the configuration.
5. Go to your **Console**. Click **EC2 Instances**. Click **Load Balancers**. Click through the load balancers. Click **Instances** and scroll down to see the EC2 instances assigned to that load balancer. If the EC2 instance has the same name as your Application URL (or something close), take note of the **DNS Name** for the load balancer. It should be in the format `awseb-e-...`
6. Go back to your **Console**. Click **CloudFront**. Click **Create Distribution**. Select a **Web** distribution.
7. Set up the distribution. Set your **Origin Domain Name** to the load balancer DNS name you found in **step 5**. Set the **Viewer Protocol Policy** to **Redirect HTTP to HTTPS**. Set **Forward Query Strings** to **Yes**.   Set **Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)** to the URL(s) you want to use for your application. Set **SSL Certificate** to the `CERTIFICATE_NAME` you uploaded in **step 2**. Create your distribution.
8. Click on your distribution name in CloudFront. Click **Origins**, select your origin, and click **Edit**. Ensure your **Origin Protocol Policy** is **Match Viewer**. Go back. Click **Behaviors**, select your origin, and click **Edit**. Change **Forward Headers** to **Whitelist** and add **Host**. Save.
9. Go to your **Console**. Click **Route 53**. Click **Hosted Zones**. Click **Create Hosted Zone**. Set up your domain name. Once set up, click **Create Record Set**. Enter your A record. Select **Alias** as **Yes**. Your **Alias Target** is your CloudFront distribution. Save the record.
10. Set up your nameservers for your domain to point to the Route 53 nameservers. Wait for everything to propagate, which could be a few hours. Go to your URL. You will be automatically redirected to HTTPS.
11. "But wait, my links don't go to HTTPS!?" You need to handle the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header that CloudFront will pass. For Laravel 4, [follow this guide](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/fix-ssl-in-laravel-4-when-server-is-behind-a-load-balancer-or-a-reverse-proxy). For Laravel 5, run this:

    ```
    php artisan make:middleware EB_SSL_Trust
    ```

And then add this to the `EB_SSL_Trust` file:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->setTrustedProxies( [ $request->getClientIp() ] );
        return $next($request);
    }
```

And add this to your `App\Http\Kernel.php` file:

```
    protected $middleware = [
        ...
        'App\Http\Middleware\EB_SSL_Trust',
        ...
    ];
```

**Note:** All your assets, such as CSS, JS or images, need to be sent over HTTPS. If you use Laravel to create these links, use `secure_asset()` to create the HTTPS URL in your View.

Answer (score 9):

The use of **filters** has been deprecated in **Laravel 5.1.***. This is a perfect job for a MiddleWare.

Create a Middleware and in the handle section put

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(! $request->secure()) {
        return redirect()->secure($request->path());
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Then simply register your middleware in your Kernel.php and use it with your routes or controllers.

Answer (score 7):

**Using .htaccess Apache for laravel 4.2.X**

Original File

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Edit File  /public/.htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 


    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: But this does not remove the trailing slash. Perhaps this rule is more appropriate: `RewriteRule ^(.*[^/]|)/*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]`. When it is not secure (with or without trailing slash), it redirects properly. It would also be necessary maintain the original redirection, to be matched when the protocol is correct but trailing slash exists.

Comment: Just remove `# Redirect Trailing Slashes...    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 5):

Combining previous answers and updating for Laravel 4.2:

```
Route::filter('secure', function () {
    if (! Request::secure()) {
        return Redirect::secure(
            Request::path(),
            in_array(Request::getMethod(), ['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE']) ? 307 : 302
        );
    }
});
Route::when('*', 'secure');
```

Comment: FYI, `Route::filter` code goes in **filters.php** and `Route::when ` code goes in **routes.php**. I just wanted to secure one section of my site so I added `Route::when('admin/*', 'secure');`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to redirect to the same URL but using https, you should use `Request::getRequestUri()` instead of `Request::path()`:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if( ! Request::secure())
    {
         return Redirect::secure(Request::getRequestUri());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in Apache 2.4

I changed .htaccess in Laravel's root folder

From

    `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>`

To

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a problem, where for some reason `Request::secure()` returns false, even when the url is `https`, it could be because $_SERVER['HTTPS'] value doesn't exist.

This is a workaround:

```
App::before(function ($request){
    // Force https
    if(!Request::secure() && array_get($_SERVER, 'SERVER_PORT') != 443){
        return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had a problem with forcing ssl while doing POST request.  It would always redirect to GET.  This happens because `Redirect::secure()` is by default using a 302 redirect.

To make sure your POST request are redirected properly, use something like

```
return Redirect::secure("your/path/here", 307)
```

This will make sure your request will keep original request method after redirect occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand about HTTP and HTTPS in detail, so I'm sorry if this answer isn't very good.

It's my understanding that there is an issue that even when client and (client specified) server are using HTTPS, `Request::secure()` can return false because your application may be running on a different server, which is possibly not receiving a https request.

I'm hosting my laravel app in heroku and it seems it does that. My ***guess*** is that the primary (client specified) server is a load balancer and when the request is forwarded, it arrives at the other server as a normal HTTP request.

When such forwarding can happen, you should not just check for `Request::secure()` to be `true`. I was instructed (by someone in #laravel @ irc.freenode.com) to also check `Request::server('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO')` to see if it's equal to `'https'`.

So if you intend to follow the other advice in here and perform a redirect in case of non-secure, try checking for this server parameter too.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Also: why doing this logic in the application, instead of the front server conf?

Comment: @LuisMasuelli In my case, it's because idk how to configure heroku properly. When all I had as my local apache server, it was all done through apache's configuration. I'm yet to learn more about using heroku's services.

Answer (score 1):

For laravel 5.1 you should use given code in `App\Http\Providers\RouteServiceProvider@boot`

```
$router->filter('force.ssl', function () {
      if ( ! request()->secure() ) {
           return redirect()->secure(request()->path());
      }
});
```

Now you can use this in routes file.

```
Route::group(['before' => 'force.ssl'], function () {
    // Routes here
});
```

you can also add `['before' => 'force.ssl']` in `$router->group()` in

```
App\Http\Providers\RouteServiceProvider@map
```

Answer (score 0):

If behind a proxy and Request::secure() is not working.

```
App::before( function( $request )
{
  // set the current IP (REMOTE_ADDR) as a trusted proxy
  Request::setTrustedProxies( [ $request->getClientIp() ] );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining previous answers to use constants and methods that are available in Laravel 4.2.

**routes.php**

```
Route::when('*', 'secure');
```

**filters.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response as IlluminateResponse;

Route::filter('secure', function ()
{
    if ( ! Request::secure() && Request::getPort() != 443)
    {
        return Redirect::secure(
            Request::path(),
            in_array(Request::getMethod(), ['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
                ? IlluminateResponse::HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
                : IlluminateResponse::HTTP_FOUND
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use Laravel 4 itself to handle the redirecting (like me), I'd go for the following setup (explanation as comments in the code):

Route filter:

```
// app/filters.php
Route::filter('ssl.force', function()
{
    if(App::environment('production') && !Request::secure())
    {
        // don't set a session cookie when redirecting to another scheme to 
        // avoid dropping the session when switching scheme
        Config::set('session.driver', 'array');
        // preserve query string while redirecting by using fullUrl()
        // instead of Redirect::secure + Request::path()
        $url = str_replace('http://', 'https://', Request::fullUrl());
        return Redirect::to($url, 302, array(), true);
    }

    // secure cookies for https
    Config::set('session.secure', Request::secure());
});
```

Then apply the filter as a before filter to your route or route group.
eg:

```
// app/routes.php
Route::group(array('before' => 'ssl.force'), function () {
    // SSL routes
});
```