# Laravel secure redirect filter working in my local, but not on server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a filter which redirects the user to https:// part of the site. I have tested this on my local and it works as it should, but when I test it on the live website, it doesn't work at all.

Any ideas why this would be? My local is using XAMPP running on Windows 7. My server is CentOS 6.

Here's my filter...

```
Route::filter('secure', function()
{
    if(!Request::secure())
    {
        return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
    }
};
```

And my routes

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'secure', 'prefix' => '{regionSlug}/{parkSlug}'), function(){
    // List of routes go here.
});
```

EDIT: After taking a further look, I noticed that it wasn't working properly on my local either. The only reason it worked is because of my login check which redirects and moves over to the https part of the site. Any other page inside this route group didn't actually work. I took out the https in each of my get and post routes and this managed to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried debugging in your website?

Route::get('zz', function(){
dd(Request::secure()); 
});

what does that return?

Comment: `Request::secure()` checks the contents of the `HTTPS` environment variable set by the server.  you can also try `dd($_SERVER)` in your live environment (on a test page) while over HTTPS to make sure the variable is correctly set.  Also if your website is behind a proxy that provides the SSL, you may need to do additional configuration there to make sure your application server is aware of that.

Comment: It checked it on http:// and it came back as false. Over https:// it came back as true. So it is detecting it correctly by the looks of it. The SSL is from an external site, but I still would have thought it would be able to redirect to https://.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW
**Forcing A Route To Be Served Over HTTPS**

```
Route::get('foo', array('https', function()
{
    return 'Must be over HTTPS';
}));
```

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#basic-routing

This could be your answer

```
Route::filter('secure', function()
{
    if(!Request::secure())
    {
        return Redirect::secure(Request::path(URL::to('/')));
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I have already been doing this with the routes inside my group route. :)

Comment: your welcome your secure::path() didnt have a root url to go to now it does. give it a shot.

Comment: For some reason, adding the https in the route get method is what is stopping the redirect, the minute I took it out, it started redirecting to https. I was following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967788/laravel-redirect-all-requests-to-https

Comment: It makes sense. putting https never letting browser to go to it to trigger secure filter. therefor it fails. But if your reach that path with ajax, redirect would NOT work i guess you should consider that as well. throw a forbidden or something

Comment: I wonder why the https in get methods doesn't automatically do these checks. I would have thought that it should do. Any way, thanks for helping me out on this one. :)