# Laravel include css, js using ssl

Tags: php, ssl, laravel

I just installed an SSL cert onto my web server and I'm having some issues with my laravel setup.

I'm using

```
{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
```

to include css and for js

```
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery.js') }}
```

Though when I load the page with https it seems to include the 2 with http instead of https.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had an issue with this too.  My SSL is redirecting fine, but the CSS and JS links generated by `{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}` and `HTML::script('js/script.js')` were linking to the http versions.

If you look at the [Illuminate\Html\HtmlBuilder Documentation](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Html/HtmlBuilder.html#method_style) you'll see that you can specify the secure version as follows:

`{{ HTML::style('css/style.css', array(), true) }}`

`{{ HTML::script('js/script.js', array(), true) }}`

`true` means `$secure` flag is on.

Comment: We need to add an extra parameter for each line with Html:: ?
Sorry, I think it is not good way...
Laravel must have better way

Comment: Note for Laravel 5, it is `<link href="{{ secure_asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

This might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967788/laravel-redirect-all-requests-to-https).

In short you need to add a `App:before` in the `app/filters.php`.

Comment: After applying that I get the following: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: Do you have any ModRewrite rules that could be forcing JS/CSS files to use http?