# Laravel 5 include css and js using ssl

Tags: javascript, css, ssl, heroku, laravel-5

I'm trying to include a simple css and js file into my index blade template file. In locahost works fine using the information in this link:
[Laravel include css, js using ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487754/laravel-include-css-js-using-ssl)

But on heroku is not working, i'm getting the Mixed Content error because of the http request for the css and js files.

How can i use https for linking css and js in my blade template?

Ps: `{{HTML::style('css/site.css', array(), true) }}` does not work unfortunately

Comment: You could use `secure_asset()` instead maybe ?

Comment: i'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: @Muhammet third param already define to ssl enable...

Comment: @SafoorSafdar I know, but Form helper is not embedded in Laravel 5 by default, `secure_asset()` is. So, it might help to use reliable and built-in function.

Comment: Thanks @Muhammet! secure_asset did the trick!