# Laravel: How to toggle between http and https with parental control?

Tags: php, laravel-4, https, laravel-routing

The laravel web application is in development for last 20 days. Now its required to be on `https` instead of `http`, so need to change whole code for `https` because laravel either requires to pass third parameter as `true` for script and style sheets. Or need to append or prepend `secure` word in fuction call like `secure_assets`

So my question is simple as that, can I have some parental logic by which I can efficiently manage the transfer without bothering about request method is secure or not.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967788/laravel-redirect-all-requests-to-https

Comment: by this i am going into infinite loop and chrome ends me up

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is change apache or nginx server to only serve `https` in the first place. Either in the nginx config or in a `.htaccess` file.

From there every link within Laravel will automatically be `https://yourdomain.com` without any need for a single line of code change.

Comment: That's right! The `secure` option is only to *force* https.