# Request assets via https in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I want my site to work via `https` so I setup `.htaccess` correctly but now when I open site, all assets loaded via

```
asset('/assets/css/style.css')
```

Are loaded via `http`. In config/app.php I have URL set with https, but both `asset` and `Request::root()` return `http`

How do I solve this?

I know `asset()` can accept second parameter `true` and return `https` but it's not really a solution to change that everywhere. Especially if I have to go back to `http` at some point

Comment: Are you running behind something like CloudFlare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force CloudFlare to https, check out their [documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203291960-Does-enabling-Universal-SSL-automatically-force-https-).

You might redirect all unsecure requests to their secure counterparts, check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https).

Comment: Ok, but is there a way for Laravel to generate `https` URL? This would be redirection and a lot of redirections

Comment: Yeah sure, you can force https; use `secure_asset()` instead of `asset()`.

Comment: This still requires lots of changes to code. So there is no way to tell laravel to use https globally for `Request::root()` and `asset()`. Thanks anyway

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check it out.