# Laravel secure action function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to make all actions https friendly? Right now the helpers 'action' doesn't secure my links if I put https in my URL.

```
<form action="{{ action('LoginController@postLogin') }}" method="post"></form>
```

Comment: Use a middleware to force HTTPS everywhere instead of writing it individiually.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https