# Laravel route not found with https

Tags: php, http, https, laravel-5

I have a simple route defined in routes.php on top of any route:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
echo 'hello';
});
```

It is working when access through http but it gives:

```
The requested URL /test was not found on this server.
```

When I try to access through https.

I have searched a lot on internet but couldn’t find any solution.

My main page is loading with both http and https but other routes not working. Do I need some extra configurations?

**Edit:**

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


</IfModule>
```

Please guide me.

Thanx.

Comment: I think this will work even in 5.2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https

Answer (score 5):

- Update the `APP_URL` in your `.env` file so it starts with `https://` instead of `http://`:

  `APP_URL=https://yourserver.com`
- Add this to your SSL Apache config (on Ubuntu: `default-ssl.conf`):

```
<Directory /var/www/public/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work for me" would be more appropriate, @RaeIan. Nothing has changed in Laravel 5.8 (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/releases) that would make this fix obsolete. APP_URL is still there and the rest is Apache configuration that has nothing to do with the Laravel version. You simply have a different problem.

Comment: it works as expected, perfect thank you mate!

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issues and I resolved it by simply modified my .htaccess  file. Generally this is problem with our rewrite module.
try this hope it work for you.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also make sure folder structures match on local and production servers.

Comment: Please have a look on my .htaccess should I need to change it? since I paste your .htaccess and it gives internal server error.

Comment: replace the <your project path> with your project path

Comment: just add this line in your .htaccess file 'RewriteBase <your project path>'

Comment: I did what you suggested but It gives internal server error for all routes. . but main page is loading properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109754/discussion-between-ankur-tiwari-and-user2517610).

Comment: @AnkurTiwari was it resolved ? i am also facing the same problem !