# Laravel Redirect Http to Https

Tags: php, laravel, http, https

We use Laravel 5. For redirecting http connection to https  use Middleware HttpsProtocol.

```
namespace MyApp\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class HttpsProtocol {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
            if (!$request->secure() && env('APP_ENV') === 'prod') {
                return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
            }

            return $next($request); 
    }
}
```

In our 4 test case correctly works only 1 (last redirect). Other 3 case Middleware adds url extra index.php.

http://www.aqualink.az/index.php --->   https://www.aqualink.az/index.php/index.php
http://aqualink.az/index.php ---> https://aqualink.az/index.php/index.php
https://www.aqualink.az/index.php --->  https://www.aqualink.az/index.php/index.php
https://aqualink.az/index.php ---> https://aqualink.az/index.php

Comment: try this [Laravel 5 - redirect to HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https)

Comment: We use same method Mr Purushotam Thakur

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved with htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better to use web server to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS. Sample VH config for Apache:

```
<VirtualHost test.app:80>
   ServerName test.app
   Redirect permanent / https://test.app
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost test.app:443>
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It also clarifies that you have have two rules for port 80 (http) and port 443 (https).

Answer (score 2):

After change on virtual host,you can use that .htaccess on public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```