# How to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS without using .htaccess file in laravel 5.2

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

I want to redirect the HTTP traffic to HTTPS without using .htaccess file in laravel 5.2?
How can i do that, Any solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "off"){
    $redirect = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: ' . $redirect);
    exit();
}
```

For Laravel 5.2 you can do this:

create new middleware (you can do it by command `php artisan make:middleware nameMiddleware`, eg. `php artisan make:middleware forceSSL`

In this middleware (/app/Http/Middleware/nameMiddleware.php) put this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class nameMiddleware {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        if (!$request->secure() && env('APP_ENV') === 'prod') {
            return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Register your middleware in /app/http/Kernel.php

```
$middlewares = [
...
'\app\Http\Middleware\nameMiddleware'
];
```

Add the middleware to `$routeMiddleware` array.

After this, you can add the middleware directly into `Route::get('/', ['middleware' => 'nameMiddleware'] ...);`

Comment: Thanks brother, your code is running in core php, but i need to run it in laravel where it is not working ?

Comment: You can create a filter:

`Route::filter('f.ssl', function()
{
    if( ! Request::secure())
    {
        return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
    }

});`

Comment: How to create a filter ? can you pleae elaborate

Comment: Brother i am using laravel 5.2

Comment: and there are no filters in laravel 5.2 as far i know

Comment: your answer is also right, but the proper procedure is described here which i have follow and worked. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https