# How to implement HTTPS in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, https

I have a shared hosting with OVH(France) and i have the "Let's Encrypt" certificate for my domain.

however, i looked everywhere for redirecting all requests from HTTP to HTTPS in laravel 5.4

i have found a solution with ".htacces redirecting" but i often have "TOO_MANY_REDIRECT" errors on browsers specially Google Chrome.

Anyone have an idea for redirecting all 
PS : i don't have "sudo" rights on my shared hosting server (just user access with ssh)

Regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modify the **.htaccess** file, you can force the https protocol in your Laravel application adding:

```
function boot() {
     URL::forceScheme('https');
     ... your code
}
```

In your `AppServiceProvider.php`.

Comment: Thank you @Troyer,
i added "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;" in AppServiceProvider and it's works
However, if i try to access to my web site by removing "https://" it's not redirecting me to https.
Redirecting to https works only if i click on a link in my web site to go on login or about page.
Is there any way to force redirecting from http to https (i dont want http anymore)
Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: @aymanesoft Found a very good answer that fits your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https

Answer (score 0):

You can set `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://localhost'),` in `config/app.php`. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @Troyer answer, i added the code below to my .htacces

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

and now all request to HTTP are redirected to HTTPS without the "TOO_MANY_REDIRECT" errors
thank you very much guys for your answers
best regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to force HTTPS over all URLs of your app without having to change your `Apache` or `Nginx` configuration, you need to update your `AppServiceProvider` as followed:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
            $this->app['url']->forceScheme('https');
        }
    }
}
```

PS: you can remove the condition if you have SSL enabled on your local development environment.