# Problems with https in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, laravel-5

I have an VPS with vestacp installed. I have ssl certificate using letsencrypt.
I have installed laravel and works fine when I try to load it via http. But when I try to load it via https I get a 403 error and a forbidden message.
I have already tried some things like

[How to implement HTTPS in laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113859/how-to-implement-https-in-laravel-5-4)

And using middleware like this other thread.

[Laravel 5 - redirect to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https/32258661#32258661)

But I'm still getting same error.

Comment: Sounds like you might not have a virtualhost set up correctly for HTTPS traffic

Comment: did u set up the vHost on your server for HTTPS?

Comment: you are right. I only configured one conf file. I didn't realized there where another file for https.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to edit sapache2.conf file.
Now it is fixed