# htaccess - Laravel force https

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect

I've a problem of redirection with my htacess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    #http > https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(api/list|api/categories)
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

And i'v had this in my AppServiceProvider in boot méthod

```
if(env('APP_ENV') == 'production'){
  \URL::forceScheme("https");
}
```

The problem is the following :
when i call url myndd.fr i'm redirect to HTTPS that's OK.
But when i call

- myndd.fr/api/list
- myndd.fr/api/categories

i'm redirect to https://myndd.fr/index.php?params_url
and for this specific route i don't want be redirect to https.

Any idea ?

Thanks for you'r help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28403907/6030030

Answer (score 2):

You have to exclude index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On

    #http > https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?index\.php$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(api/list|api/categories) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On

    #http > https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(api/list|api/categories) [NC]
    RewriteRule https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```