# Cannot get TrustProxies middleware to work

Tags: laravel, load-balancing, laravel-5.5, laravel-middleware

After pointed in the right direction here [Laravel 5.4 relative instead of absolute 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47167247/laravel-5-4-relative-instead-of-absolute-302-redirects)
I've been trying to get Laravel TrustProxies middleware to work, but seems to be ignoring X_FORWARDED_PROTO header.

**My scenario**
My app in Laravel (just upgraded from 5.4 to 5.5) is behind a load balancer, which translates all traffic from HTTPS to HTTP.

**My problem**
All redirects are going over HTTP instead of original protocol HTTPS.

**Attempted Solution**
Upgrade from Laravel 5.4 to 5.5 and take advantage of the TrustProxies middleware now shipped with Laravel out of the box.
Middleware has:

```
protected $proxies = '*';

/**
 * The current proxy header mappings.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $headers = [
    Request::HEADER_FORWARDED => 'FORWARDED',
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR => 'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST => 'X_FORWARDED_HOST',
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT => 'X_FORWARDED_PORT',
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO => 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO',
];
```

App\Http\Kernel has registered the middleware:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
];
```

**My findings:**
Tcp dump from the server reveals the header:

*Request:*

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
X_FORWARDED_PROTO: HTTPS
Host: mywebsiteaddress.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

*But the Response has Location over HTTP:*

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 08 Nov 2017 18:03:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Location: http://mywebsiteaddress.com/home
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJp...In0%3D; expires=Wed, 08-Nov-2017 20:03:48 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Length: 376
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**Additional comments:**
Since my app was upgraded from 5.4 to 5.5, I copied the class TrustProxies that otherwise would've been there in a 5.5 fresh installation. Then I registered it in the Kernel.
Maybe I'm missing a step here.

**My hope:**
That my tiredness is not clouding my mind that I'm overlooking a simple mistake.

Any suggestions, thank you in advance!

**Update:**
Enabled log_forensics module in Apache and I see the x-forwarded-proto header in the request.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
X_FORWARDED_PROTO:HTTPS
Host:mywebsiteaddress.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv%3a56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Connection:keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
Cache-Control:max-age=0
```

Any clue why Laravel may not have in the headers array?

Comment: BTW, I did a dd($_SERVER); in routes/web.php right before the redirection and couldnt' find the X_FORWARED_PROTO in the headers.

Comment: Did it work on while you are on 5.4?

Comment: @Suraj I didn't test on 5.4 since it represented more manual config, meaning more risk of making mistakes. I chose to better upgrade to 5.5 considering it as higher probability of success. 
I'm about to test in a fresh 5.5 mock application, but requires collaboration with my network team to replicate the scenario

Comment: are you using AWS load balancer?

Comment: No @Suraj, it's our own hardware load balancer. Right now is just used to expose our apps to the internet with a wildcard ssl certificate.  All apps behind this load balancer are listening in HTTP. But I'm only having this issue with Laravel apps.

Comment: I'm thinking this may be an issue in Apache vhost, since I don't see this header reaching Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed tiredness.
The load balancer has been working with X_FORWARDED_PROTO header for C# (IIS) apps, so the network team set the header the same way this time.
But for Laravel, the header has to be in the form of **X-FORWARDED-PROTO** which I understand is the right name (dashes instead of underscores).
That is why Laravel (Symfony in reality) was discarding the header from the request.