# .htaccess - how to redirect https:// to http:// for specific url

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

This is my current .htaccess file. My project has https:// already but i wanted to open specific url without https . Is there any way i could forces one specific url to http?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine On

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

        # Handle Authorization Header
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/specific-url [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/specific-url [NC]` will skip `/specific-url` for `http -> https` redirection.

Comment: suppose the url which i don't want to open with https is `abc.com/demo`
the should i write `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/demo [NC]`

Comment: @anubhava Can it be somehow passed multiple exact URLs in oneliner like array or list?

Comment: Yes it can be done e.g. `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(demo|demo1|demo2) [NC]`

Comment: I did but noting happened actually.The url which i don't want to open with https still loads with https

Comment: Test in a new browser or use command line curl for testing. Also update question with latest .htaccess

Comment: btw this rule only prevents `http -> https` redirection. So your URL should be: `http://example.com/demo` (not https)