# Laravel 5.6 http://127.0.0.1:8000/ redirecting to https://127.0.0.1:8000/login (https)

Tags: php, laravel

I have laravel 5.6 site built in local, after running

```
php artisan serve
```

it shows Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000, but when i enter this URL in browser it always redirect to https site, **https://127.0.0.1:8000/login**

I have check the followings:

1) in `.env` file environment is `local`

2) checked .htaccess file for redirection

3) checked middleware for if there is any redirection

What will be the problem?

Comment: There's most likely an authentication middleware in the index. Check your routes.

Comment: @GiamPy: Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https)

Comment: @arun: try this and restart app, php artisan route:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear

Comment: working on the above three solutions

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravels's `ForceHttps Middleware` to force `https` or `http` depending on the environment you're working on.

For example, I prefer to use HTTP on my local environment but to enforce HTTPS on the production environment.

In `.env`, set `APP_ENV=local`

Then, add the following in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` in the `boot` method.

```
       if($this->app->environment('production')) {
            \URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
```

You can also use:

```
    if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
       \URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
```

Remember to always change `.env` on production environment to set `APP_ENV=production`

Answer (score 0):

**https** issue solved by changing this:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://localhost'),
//into
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```

in your **config/app.php** file.

Comment: checked APP_URL in both .env file and in config/app file, no https present there

Comment: You can place this in the **AppServiceProvider** in the **boot()** method, or maybe create a ForceHttpsMiddleware:

if($this->app->environment('production')) {
    URL::forceScheme('http');
}