# Laravel .htaccess configuration for excluding POST endpoint from https

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

In my Laravel app i have a POST endpoint in which Arduino sends some data. I installed SSL and tried communication again but with no result (redirect). I want to exclude only this specific endpoint from https. I tried different approaches and code that found with no result.

e.g. Route endpoint: /api/measures

.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I'm a nginx type of person myself, but from what i know you need to allow both http and https traffic and redirect http to https on all links except that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully i found a solution following a different way than changing .htaccess. With the help of Laravel i applied a middleware that redirects all web and api requests to secure requests and excluded the only endpoint that takes the request from Arduino client (can't handle ssl).

Answer that helped me [Laravel 5 - redirect to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https)