# Redirect website http to https in laravel in shared hosting using htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ssl

I have a Laravel project. and I used Godaddy. Recently, I installed an SSL certificate on my website so when I type https://example.com in the browser it works but when I write example.com, it connects by HTTP.

To fix that, I added these lines to my root folder's .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But this redirects to me https://example.com/public.

I added two htaccess one is in the root folder and the second one is in public folder.

first htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Second htaccess code is :

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]


# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

How can I achieve this `https://example.com`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on?

Comment: try this `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: @fmsthird in which .htaccess I put this code.

Comment: the first one in your root folder

Comment: @fmsthird i tried this already it redirect perfectly but in url it https://example.com/public

Comment: I hope, This will help you do this ? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https)

Comment: how about `RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1  [R=301,L]`

Comment: @RopAliMunshi yes but its give me forbidden access error

Comment: Hey @Dhaval_512 did you find the solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Please, look at this https://gist.github.com/ilhamsj/819369a56bb983eac018c5f4e04cda50

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the Solution,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   # Force SSL
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   # Remove public folder form URL
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    #redirect http non-www to https://www
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?your-domain\.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.your-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    #redirect https non-www to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your-domain\.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.your-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I am using this to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Tried every solution but this worked for me on **Laravel 6.0**, use this by **creating .htaccess file in root folder** rather than /public/.htaccess file.

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On

# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  
# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```