# Force http to https redirect in Laravel (without "www") in URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8. This is my htacess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I make redirect from http://name.com, http://www.name.com, https://www.name.com to https://name.com?

It's posible in htacess or Middleware?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - redirect to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is .htaccess snippet for force redirect HTTP to https

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /
       Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    ​
       RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
       RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:https]
    ​
       RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
       RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:http]
    ​
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!(^|/)\.well-known/([^./]+./?)+$" [NC]
       RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
       RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
       RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
    ​
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname\.com$ [NC]
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainname.com$1 [R=301,L]
    ​
       RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  !=on
       RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://domainname.com/$1 [R,L]
    ​
    ​
    ​
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    ​
    </IfModule>`