# Laravel 5.4 with SSL

Tags: security, laravel-5, ssl-certificate

I developed a site with Laravel 5.4.

I just installed an SSL certificate and added this to my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

I also added this in my AppServiceProvider:

```
URL::forceScheme('https');
```

When I go to mysite.co.za it changes to https but when I go to my admin section: mysite.co.za/admin it does not and it shows me an 'i' icon instead of a lock icon on the address bar.

Clicking on the 'i' icon says the site is not secured.

My host reply: This is most likely a configuration issue where the site is using mixed content.
I have no idea what they mean and how to fix it.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: “Mixed content” means you’re loading something on the page using `http://`, i.e. an image, style sheet, JavaScript file, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Martin Bean, found and fixed

Comment: Actually, checking again, not totally fixed. For some reason when I look at the console I see my own site referenced as http but it is in files under: storage/framework/views/ with long number names, can I delete these files?. It also shows the AntiVirus I use: gc.kis.v2.scr.kasperskey-labs.com, not sure what is that doing there and how to remove it.

Comment: It shows Main origin: mysite.co.za with http and I don't have any links in my code like that. The ksapersky one is in the Non-secure origins section.

Comment: If I go to: mysite.co.za/bean with https entered manually, all is fine, if I don't add the https manually it gives the unsecure links

Comment: Ok, another try, if I manually put http in the address, it redirects to https but without http it just stays as is and becomes not secure. How do I redirect mysite.co.za to add the https to it?

Comment: I found out if I'm already logged in to the site and I go to mysite.co.za/admin with no http or www it does not redirect, otherwise it goes to secure login and all is secured. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on this post:

[Laravel 5 - redirect to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https)

using na-98 answer.

Thank you