# Trying to get http instead of http ressources - error: mixed active content

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel / PHP (and vuejs)

I have no idea what changed, I have been working on https for some months now, and suddently it seems like all redirections are trying to visit http pages instead of https.

For example the login controller

```
public function redirectTo(){
        $type = Auth::user()->type; 
        switch ($type) {
            case 'O':
                    return '/blabla';
                break;
            default:
                    return '/home'; //this page is going to http://mywebsite.com/home instead of https://mywebsite.com/home
                break;
        }
    }
```

when adding ->secure(), it works, but I don't think I should add it in all my project...

```
return redirect()->secure('/test');
```

I'm sorry the error is in french:
*Blocage du chargement du contenu mixte actif (mixed active content) « http://mywebsite.com/home »
TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." app.js:1:2175324
Blocage d’une requête multiorigines (Cross-Origin Request) : la politique « Same Origin » ne permet pas de consulter la ressource distante située sur https://ip2c.org/s. Raison : échec de la requête CORS.*

Here is my .env file:

```
APP_NAME=MYWEBSITE
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=https://mywebsite.com
MIX_APP_URL=https://mywebsite.com
```

Comment: did you check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https