# Asset is direct to HTTP but when it on server they trying to request HTTPS

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx

i'm using Laravel 5 with php7.4
So i put this into header

```
<script src="http://10.105.2.10/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And this is what they trying to get https

```
GET https://10.105.2.10/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Its work well on local but when deploy to test server it's not working
And the weird thing is other page is work fine but only one page had this problem

Comment: Please write your code manually, this question will be difficult to help with other developers you just send the screenshots.


Please check on your harcoded code look like you've added https instead of http.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 - redirect to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https)

Comment: Maybe webserver like nginx or apache is rewriting the urls

Comment: Why is `http://10.105.2.10` included in the script statement?