# Laravel - Make laravel 5 app use https

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, application-settings

I'm using latest version of laravel 5.2, I want to run the hole app on `HTTPS` protocol

what I found from searching is:

1. setup a filter, but `filter.php`is not found any more in this
   version
2. setup the server in somehow to make it, but I couldn't because I'm new
3. implementing a middleware, I couldn't understand it too

I want to implement https in my application, what is the best way and how?
I would be thankful for a detailed answer.

Note: developing on local host, XAMP used, Windows 10.

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some more research to understand the problem you are trying to solve. Post some code and someone will be able to help

Comment: refrences :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967788/laravel-redirect-all-requests-to-https
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554636/laravel-make-laravel-5-app-use-https
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https

Answer (score 1):

You could use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware):

```
class HttpsMiddleware {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ( ! $request->secure() && app()->environment() === 'production') {
            return redirect()->secure($request->path());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```