# Laravel 4.2 method not allowed SSL POST

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

```
Route::post('/login-details',array('https','HomeController@login_details'));
```

But the same thing is working in http POST
and all GET URL also working only form POST SSL not working?
Any clue?

Comment: Do you have SSL?

Comment: yes..I have ssl.. and its working on .all site GET request.. except for POST

Comment: I have never seen the `array('https','HomeController@login_details')` part before. If you want to force the HTTPS for the specific POST route you coult [try](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19968614/6140684) another way

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos My All request are working https. Not having problem of redirection of https.. Its just in POST Form Ajax request is showing method not allowed..exception

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos  https://marcepinc.com/careers
Please check form and ajax request.. same working in http

Comment: The error is "{type: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException", message: "",…}
file
:
"/home/marcea2y/public_html/marcepinc.com/bootstrap/compiled.php"
line
:
3747
message
:
""
type
:
"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException""

Comment: You will have to add the crsf token to the ajax post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149983/discussion-between-antonis-tsimourtos-and-user2937883).

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos  Yes.. Any solution for that?

Comment: I have the same problem here.
All GET requests work except for POST request using SSL.
Any solutions?