# AWS EB Apache mod_wsgi configuration

Tags: python, apache, amazon-web-services, mod-wsgi

I'm using AWS EB Python container.

I wish to change Apache mod_wsgi configuration, but it's automatically overwritten by default setting after EC2 instance reboot. (or, re-deployment of application version).

How can I use my own mod_wsgi configuration smart way?
As I understood, it's overwritten by config.py file in /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not elegant way I think, but for someone who can met similar situation.
Try to modify `config.py` file in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks` folder.
You can find `APACHE_TEMPLATE` variable. Please add your own configuration to this string.
And, upload your new S/W version. That's all.

UPDATE: I found better solution:
- [How to force https on elastic beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693852/how-to-force-https-on-elastic-beanstalk)