# AWS EB - Redirect all traffic to https

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My nodejs app is deployed on AWS EB. I already configured the https server and it is working fine. Now I need to redirect every non-https request to https with the www. as prefix, like this:

```
GET example.com => https://www.example.com
```

**I'm using nginx and my EB instance is a single instance without load balancer in front of it.**

I have created a config file in the .ebextensions folder with this code

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/999_nginx.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |

      upstream nodejsserver {
        server 127.0.0.1:8081;
        keepalive 256;
      }

      # HTTP server

      server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;
        return        301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }

      # HTTPS server

      server {
        listen       443;
        server_name  localhost;

        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

        location / {
          proxy_pass  http://nodejsserver;
          proxy_set_header   Connection "";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header        Host                $host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto   https;
        }
      }

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      my crt
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      my key
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

  /etc/nginx/conf.d/gzip.conf:
    content: |
      gzip on;
      gzip_comp_level 9;
      gzip_http_version 1.0;
      gzip_types text/plain text/css image/png image/gif image/jpeg application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/rdf+xml;
      gzip_proxied any;
      gzip_disable "msie6";

commands:
   00_enable_site:
    command: 'rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*'
```

I'm sure aws is taking in account my config because de ssl is working fine. But the http block does not work.. There is no redirect.

**Maybe my problem is about rewriting the original nginx config of EB, do you know how to achieve this ?**

Can you help me with that please ? I've tried a lot of things..

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force https on elastic beanstalk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693852/how-to-force-https-on-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: Forgot to say that i'm using nginx and eb on a single instance without load balancer in front of it!

Comment: Did you search for something like "Nginx force SSL"? There are tons of answers to this question already out there.

Comment: Yes sure. I tried a lot of things, nothing worked for my case..

Comment: You can have Cloudfront and S3 redirect functionality to handle this. Have Cloudfront redirect all requests to https and then have S3 redirect your naked domain to www.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, found the issue, EB creates a default config file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf` which is listening to 8080.  So your re-direct isn't being picked up as Nginx is using the earlier defined rule for 8080.

Here's a config file that I use that works.  The file it generates will precede the default rule.

https://github.com/jozzhart/beanstalk-single-forced-ssl-nodejs-pm2/blob/master/.ebextensions/https-redirect.config

Comment: Thank you Jozzhart, gonna try this asap :)