# Redirect http to https on Elastic Beanstalk Linux Tomcat 8

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, mod-rewrite, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

For the past several days I have been trying to force my application to forward a non https call to my domain to an https one.

I have a Web Server elastic beanstalk configured with 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03, v2.2.0 running Tomcat 8 Java 8. I created a folder in my app named .ebextensions with a file named ssl_rewrite.config. The file contains this:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
      RewriteRule !/status https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

It used to contain this, [taken from this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693852/how-to-force-https-on-elastic-beanstalk/38751749#38751749), but I was getting errors for the if statement:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        RewriteEngine On
        <If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
        </If>
```

Anyway, when I try to deploy my app it fails and I get this error:

```
Application update failed at 2016-10-17T01:33:00Z with exit status 1 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03_configure_proxy.sh failed.

Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/log-conf -n httpd -l'/var/log/httpd/*'

Executing: /usr/sbin/apachectl -t -f /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf:
Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Failed to execute '/usr/sbin/apachectl -t -f /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/httpd/conf/httpd.conf'
Failed to execute '/usr/sbin/apachectl -t -f /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/httpd/conf/httpd.conf'.
```

I have already gone into the httpd.conf file and added the line:

**LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so**

Any tips or ideas on what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who struggled for some time, I've found a GitHub (from AWS team) with all AWS configs and the example below works for the HTTP>HTTPS redirection for Apache 2.2.  (For configs for Apache 2.4 and Nginx please see the link below).

**Apache 2.2**

1. Create a file in the root directory of your app:
   **YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT/.ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk.conf**
   (In case of using IntelliJ / Java make sure it go added to the final .WAR artifact)
2. Add the following lines to enable the redirection in the virtual host:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker
       RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

       <Proxy *>
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
       </Proxy>

       ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
       ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
       ProxyPreserveHost on

       ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

For more examples for Apache 2.4 and Nginx please visit this GitHub repository:

https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/tree/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/java-tomcat

Also, there is plenty more useful configuration and examples available.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I was able to finally get mine working with:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

In addition, I have found it easier to just place a ssl_rewrite.conf in my .ebextensions/httpd/conf.d folder and let the AWS scripts handle the rest.

Please also read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#vhosts if using virtual hosts. Mod_rewrite configurations are not inherited from the main server context by virtual hosts and therefore also require the following in each virtual hosts configuration.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

Tested on 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.4.0 running Tomcat 7 Java 7.

Comment: The key in the answer for me was creating the conf file in the `.ebextensions/httpd/conf.d` folder on Tomcat8