# AWS Elasticbeanstalk web application redirection from http to https

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my java web application on elasticbeanstalk on AWS. I have bought domain from Godaddy and ssl certificate is generated from AWS using Certification manager.

Certificate is added to load balancer.

When I add https:// in url, it works fine.

Now, I want to redirect all traffic from http to https for web application. I have tried implementing below solutions found on google and numerous forums.

1. Added Web distribution from Cloud front.
2. Added rewrite rules in elasticbeanstalk.conf file under
   /etc/httpd/conf.d/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

May I know how i can achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force https on elastic beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693852/how-to-force-https-on-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: Yes i understand it is duplicate, but none of the solution worked for me