# SSL on elastic beanstalk application only works occasionally

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running an elastic beanstalk application and have enabled SSL using AWS Certificate Manager.

However when entering "https://example.com" into the browser approximately only 50% of the time does the page show as 'secure' in Google or Firefox.

Secure:

[image]

Not secure:

[image]

Would anyone be able to provide any information on how I can isolate the cause of this problem, or have any ideas about what might be causing this to act in an intermittent manner?

Comment: What seems to be happening (based on my extremely limited view from those 2 screenshots) is that your site is allowing both access to HTTP:// and HTTPS://. You're going to need to force HTTPS, have a look at the thread I linked.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693852/how-to-force-https-on-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: Your "secure" and "not secure" origins are different. Based on the information you provided, you cannot compare them. Please post the URLs you are *really* using. Or post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout` for both URLs.