# Redirect http to https on EB

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to force the redirect from http to https so that when the user enters: http://example.com he gets redirected to https://example.com.

I've tried everything described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693852/how-to-force-https-on-elastic-beanstalk?newreg=f74e4ee59b0d4a358aa55a33894d79bd)
and I even had it working, but I have no Idea what has changed, but it's not working anymore.

I've tried several options for the RewriteCond like `!https, =http, ^http$` and the only outcome I can produce is, that the EB health check is redirected, which causes even https://example.com to have an empty response if I use !https.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     <Proxy *> 
         Order Allow,Deny
         Allow from all
     </Proxy>
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
     ProxyPreserveHost on
     LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker
     RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

I've got the following listener:
[Loadbalancer Listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDQjo.png)

I'm connecting to my ec2 instance directly via ssh to test the configurations in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk`, so I test, I restart the server `sudo httpd -k restart` and nothing changes. I've even logged the rewrite via:

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

and I can see, that admin/health is checked, but nothing else. There are also no errors in the elasticbeanstalk-error.log. The weird thing is, that I had it working and I was convinced that I had just made the changes, that I've described above, but I can't get it to work again and it's really driving me crazy!

---

**SOLVED:**

So I've solved it: the problem was not the configuration file but the Loadbalancer Listener, I needed the listener for HTTP as the following:

[image]