# Http to Https AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, redirect, https, ebextensions

I am using AWS Elasticbeanstalk for my Spring MVC web application. I want to redirect all the request to https. I tried following this [How to force https on elastic beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693852/how-to-force-https-on-elastic-beanstalk/48548156#48548156) but this didn't work for me. This code redirects to https but my app didn't work. It shows "This page isn’t working". Code for your reference

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  <Proxy *>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPreserveHost on

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: are you using load balancers? if yes, are they terminating the SSL/TLS  connection?

Comment: Yes, and i allowed 443 and configured my ssl certificate

Comment: Great, does the https website work fine when you visit it using https:// domain .com ?

Comment: No once i used this https and http both not working. But before that Https works fine. only problem it is not redirecting automatically

Comment: i noticed that after using this code secure listener port is off, then i tried to enable it then i got this error. "LoadBalancerHTTPSPort: You have specified both the @deprecated(:default.aws:elb:loadbalancer:LoadBalancerHTTPSPort) option as well as one in the new aws:elb:listener:443 namespace. The :default.aws:elb:loadbalancer:LoadBalancerHTTPSPort option will be ignored."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already tested HTTPS working fine when your website is visited with HTTPS already. If not you can add this file `.ebextensions/loadbalancer-terminatehttps.config` with content as below:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elb:listener:443:
    ListenerProtocol: HTTPS
    SSLCertificateId: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:<your-account-id>:certificate/<certificate-arn-on-aws-acm>
    InstancePort: 80
    InstanceProtocol: HTTP
```

All what's left is to configure the instances Apache config to redirect the clients visiting your website with HTTP to HTTPS, add the code below to a new file  `.ebextensions/001_ssl_rewrite.config`

**Apache 2.4+**

```
files:
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            RewriteEngine On
            <If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
            RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
            </If>
```

**Apache 2.2.X**

```
files:
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
            RewriteEngine On
            # This will enable the Rewrite capabilities
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
            # This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
            RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

You can check which Apache is installed on your Elastic Beanstalk from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.java)

For more, please read both of those answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38751749/1772245 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/40670047/1772245

Comment: check the updated answer, looks like AWS Java Beanstalk images are using an older version of Apache.

Comment: it is not redirecting, when i hit http it didn't redirect to https

Comment: try "RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http" instead of "RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on" and can you confirm that you are not getting any "Invalid command 'RewriteEngine'" errors in the logs?

Comment: also make sure you don't have any other changes done to your tomcat. You can also ssh into the instance and edit the file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf` and restart apache then test ... etc. Please let me know if you need any further questions.

Comment: i tried changing that line and no use. I didn't get any error in EB events. i checked in full logs and i couldn't find any invalid command error. I just got "File does not exist: /etc/httpd/htdocs" in elasticbeanstalk_error file

Comment: I haven't provided ssh access to my instance security group and as it is managed be EB how the changes will affect to all other instances

Comment: Hi, i noticed one new thing now, when i use the code i mentioned in question, the configuration automatically changes to secure port to disable. i tried to enable that but i got this error "LoadBalancerHTTPSPort: You have specified both the @deprecated(:default.aws:elb:loadbalancer:LoadBalancerHTTPSPort) option as well as one in the new aws:elb:listener:443 namespace. The :default.aws:elb:loadbalancer:LoadBalancerHTTPSPort option will be ignored." can you please help on this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168103/discussion-between-mostafazh-and-ponraj).

Comment: Adding that file work for me., i didn't followed other things as adding that file done the job