# I have to include :433 to access HTTPS on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, nginx, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-ebs

I'm having trouble setting up my HTTPS on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. My current problem is that, although HTTPS is working, the user **must** include the port number.

My aim is to get "example.xyz" to redirect to "https://example.xyz".
At the moment I have to go to the address: "example.xyz:433" to access the EB.

Currently, I'm only trying to the the HTTPS working for the EB Load Balancer. It will communicate with the EC2s via HTTP. Ideally I'd have end-to-end encryption, but 1 step at a time you know.

Setup:

- Node.js v8.11.1 on 64bit Amazon Linux/4.5.0
- Classic load balancer
- My logs are being sent to CloudWatch
- I have my own domain - bought through Route 53.
- I've redirected the traffic from the domain to my AWS EB using ALIAS:

  ```
   name: ""
   Type: A IPv4 (default)
   Routing Policy: Simple (default)
   Evaluate Target Health: No
  ```
- I've set up a certificate using ACM
- I've used the following *.config to get my load balancer to listen for HTTPS:

  ```
  option_settings:
    aws:elb:listener:433:
      SSLCertificateId: arn:aws:acm:us-east-X:XXXXXXXX:certificate/XXXXXXXXX
      ListenerProtocol: HTTPS
      InstancePort: 80
  ```

Resulting port setup (from EB console):

```
- Port: 80
- Protocol: HTTP
- Instance Port: 80
- SSL: ---
- Enabled: On
```

and

```
- Port: 433
- Protocol: HTTPS
- Instance Port: 80
- SSL: XXXXX
- Enabled: On
```

---

I've used both Apache & Nginx to try this. After digging through the internet I found instructions to get these servers for forcing HTTP to HTTPS. Here are the examples I've used:

Apache:

```
files:
"/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        RewriteEngine On
        <If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
        </If>
```

Nginx:

```
    files:
  "/tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh":
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "000644"
    content: |
      #! /bin/bash

      CONFIGURED=`grep -c "return 301 https" /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/webapp_healthd.conf`

      if [ $CONFIGURED = 0 ]
        then
          sed -i '/listen 80;/a \    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }\n' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/webapp_healthd.conf
          logger -t nginx_rw "https rewrite rules added"
          exit 0
        else
          logger -t nginx_rw "https rewrite rules already set"
          exit 0
      fi
container_commands:
  00_appdeploy_rewrite_hook:
    command: cp -v /tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact
  01_configdeploy_rewrite_hook:
    command: cp -v /tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact
  02_rewrite_hook_perms:
    command: chmod 755 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh
  03_rewrite_hook_ownership:
    command: chown root:users /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh
```

Apache source: [How to force https on elastic beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693852/how-to-force-https-on-elastic-beanstalk)

Nginx source: https://adamjstevenson.com/tutorials/2017/02/02/configuring-and-forcing-https-for-aws-elastic-beanstalk.html

---

Both servers seem to have the some problem **however** I haven't been able to access the apache logs as they haven't turned up in my CloudWatch.

But here is the behaviour I observe along with logs from the nginx server:

**1)**
*Go to: example.xyz:433*

> Works correctly, browser says we are secure. Nginx log out:

```
172.31.16.42 - - [16/May/2018:07:54:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36" "171.6.246.51"
```

*Note that the 304 direct setup for nginx is working*

---

**2)**
*Go to: example.xyz*

> Request spins for ages, eventually times out.

No logout output. But when the request eventually times out the address bar is filled with : https://example.xyz/ which to me is another indication the redirection is working.

---

Can anyone suggest how to sort this out? Let me know if you need more information.

Cheers

Comment: You're using port 433. HTTPS is over 443.

Comment: @EvyatarMeged wow, what a stupid typo. Thanks I'll try that. #noob-lyf

Comment: That worked (of course). Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Happy to help =)

Answer (score 1):

Stupidly was using 433 instead of 443. That's sorted it all out. Thanks to @Evyatar Meged for pointing it out.