# AWS certificate manager https configuration for domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

I have a slight problem with SSL.

Currently if I were to route to my domain as example.com, it goes to the http version instead of the https version.

However, if I were to force https://example.com, it stays as https://example.com

I'm wondering what I have to do on the certificate manager side of AWS to get https working when I type in example.com without the https.

I have already configured my route 53 aliases for my domain to route to my elastic beanstalk url. I also have an SSL certificate for my domain example.com and *.domain.com that were both validated successfully, that are Amazon issued and also In Use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried redirecting http traffic (80) to https (443)? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693852/how-to-force-https-on-elastic-beanstalk) contains the steps

For ALBs, you can follow the below steps,

1.Add lister for https and forward the traffic to the target group

2.Add Lister for http and forward the traffic to https

[image]

Final Setup:
[image]

Comment: these seem to be dated answers from more than 3 years ago, is there an easier way to configure this on the elastic beanstalk load balancer GUI?

Comment: Updated the answer for the ELBs

Comment: Happy to help Shaun!

Comment: I have a follow up question with regards to forwarding www.example.com to example.com I tried using Alias and CNames to map www.example.com to example.com, problem is that www.example.com always goes to example.com. I looked up url redirects but route53 doesnt do URL records. Is there a way around this?

Comment: That means you get the redirection as you want. Do you want www.example.com and example.com to be separate?