# Setting cache control headers for Apache proxy on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk server running an Apache proxy on Amazon Linux 2. I want to set the cache-control header on my index.html file to `public, max-age=0`.

In order to update my Apache config I understand I can add a config file to `.platform/httpd/conf.d`. In my first attempt I created this file:

```
<FilesMatch "index\.html">
   Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=0"
</FilesMatch>
```

This did not work. Looking around I think this is because the directives I have used are intended for Apache's htaccess file or within a `<VirtualHost>` section of the conf file.

Any ideas how I can get this working? Note I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693852/how-to-force-https-on-elastic-beanstalk) had some useful information.

EDIT: I also tried this in a conf file (it didn't set any cache-control headers).

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Turn on the module.
ExpiresActive on
# Set the default expiry times.
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

EDIT: I also tried switching to nginx. I added a file `.platform/nginx/conf.d/cache.conf`, with the following contents

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires 2d;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
}
```

After deployment and a server restart, no cache-control headers were set on the files  specified.

Comment: Did you ever sort this?  I've just noticed I have same issue.

Comment: I couldn't get it working using ELB configurations, no. In the end I used a CloudFront Lambda Edge script. Basically, a very simple 'origin response' script that adds the required header.