# Redirect http to https using Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, ssl, redirect, https

I am using an [application load balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/applicationloadbalancer/) to map certain paths to one server (Apache) and other paths to another server (Tomcat).

I made all pages on my site available via https by setting up an [https listener](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html) on the load balancer.

So that requests from client to load balancer are encrypted but from load balancer to servers are not.

Now, I would also like to redirect all http requests to https.

Are there any suggestions how I can do this?

I can redirect each server separately (ie: redirect tomcat http requests as outlined [here](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-http-https-tomcat/) and redirect Apache http request with redirect rules). However, I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do it (ie: where I would only have 1 redirect rather than a separate redirect for each server).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into implementing HSTS? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

Comment: Thanks. I did not know much about HSTS, but as I understand it, even if I do implement HSTS I would need to do so in addition to redirects (not instead of)...Therefore my question still stands.

Comment: The load balancer isn't capable of issuing redirects. You have to configure your web servers to check the `x-forwarded-proto` value and issue the appropriate redirect.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB, is there some documentation for how best to do this for Tomcat?

Comment: Here lies the answer to your struggle:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51540255/9180019

Answer (score 1):

I found this while I was looking for a solution for the same problem. This has code sample for Apache, Nginx and IIS.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the following to conf/server.xml

```
<Connector
port="8080"
protocol="HTTP/1.1"
scheme="https"
secure="true"
connectionTimeout="20000"
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
redirectPort="8443" />
```

Please ensure scheme="https" is added so that no http request is being made.

Along with above add the default HSTS filters available in the conf/web.xml as defined in the tomcat documentation.

Please refer here for more info: [Tomcat behind LB](https://willwarren.com/2014/01/27/running-apache-tomcat-with-ssl-behind-amazon-elb/)