# AWS Load Balancer - Can't add https redirect/rules section not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am trying to add a simple HTTP to HTTPS redirect using AWS Application Load Balancer but it seems that all tutorials are out to date:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

I didn't see any option to add Rules under the load balance console, I also checked for this option on AWS CDK and haven't find anything.

The Load Balancer was created by an Elastic Beanstalk app, so I assume that it's an Application Load Balance.

I've seen a lot of tutorials and remind myself of doing same thing last year but now I don't see any option to set rules/redirects using the new AWS Console.

[Redirecting EC2 Elastic Load Balancer from HTTP to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603620/redirecting-ec2-elastic-load-balancer-from-http-to-https)

This is the only option I am seeing available at the console under `listener` sections:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, turns out that ELB allows setting Load balance type only at the creation time. In my case, I created my stack as a single instance and add a load balance latter, so AWS automatically sets the default load balancer as the CLASSIC one instead of the application load balance (where we can use targets, rules, etc).

So I had to recreate my environment setting the correct load balancer type.

Answer (score 2):

> The Load Balancer was created by an Elastic Beanstalk app, so I assume that it's an Application Load Balance

Actually, it's a Classic load balancer. You can tell because the listener config specifies the load balancer point *and* the instance port. For an Application load balancer, the instance configuration is part of the target group.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that AWS doesn't create an Application Load Balancer by default.