# How to add multiple keys for elastic beanstalk instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

There is a very good question on [[How to] SSH to Elastic [an] Beanstalk instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742478/ssh-to-elastic-beanstalk-instance), but one thing I noticed is that, through this method, it is only possible to add one SSH key.

How can I add multiple SSH keys to an instance? Is there a way to automatically add multiple keys to new instances?

Comment: My answer below explains how to do this dynamically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46269015/4245294

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, Elastic Beanstalk only supports a single key pair. You can manually add SSH keys to the `authorized_keys` file, but these will not be known to the Elastic Beanstalk tools.

Answer (score 46):

To create a file named `.ebextensions/authorized_keys.config` is another way to do it.

```
files:
  /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    content: |
      ssh-rsa AAAB3N...QcGskx keyname
      ssh-rsa BBRdt5...LguTtp another-key
```

The name of file `authorized_keys.config` is arbitrary.

Comment: This works perfectly. However, by default the authorized_keys will already have one ssh key (you have to choose one when creating the environment) and you need to remember to add that key to this file or it will be erased on deploy and you can lost the access to the server.

Comment: ^ and to get the ssh key `eb ssh` into the instance and type `cat ~ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: During subsequent deployments wont it append keyname and another-key each time? Leading to duplications until you rebuild the environment?

Comment: @Max No it won't. It will overwrite `authorized_keys`.

Comment: This is a great solution - I wonder is it possible to add these files via an environment variable, in which case you would be able to manage access without rebuilding an environment?

Comment: I'm glad I scrolled down until I found the right (laziest) answer. This should be it!

Comment: I had to quote the filename to get this to work, but works never the less

Comment: worked perfect. Only thing I had to do was open port 22 in the security group and bound that to my IP.

Answer (score 27):

Combining rhunwicks's and rch850's answers, here's a clean way to add additional SSH keys, while preserving the one set through the AWS console:

```
files:
  /home/ec2-user/.ssh/extra_authorized_keys:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    content: |
      ssh-rsa AAAB3N...QcGskx keyname
      ssh-rsa BBRdt5...LguTtp another-key
commands:
  01_append_keys:
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/
    command: sort -u extra_authorized_keys authorized_keys -o authorized_keys
  99_rm_extra_keys:
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/
    command: rm extra_authorized_keys
```

Note that `eb ssh` will work only if the private key file has the same name as the private key defined in the AWS console.

Answer (score 14):

Following on from Jim Flanagan's answer, you could get the keys added to every instance by creating `.ebextensions/app.config` in your application source directory with contents:

```
commands:
  copy_ssh_key_userA: 
    command: echo "ssh-rsa AAAB3N...QcGskx userA" >> /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
  copy_ssh_key_userB: 
    command: echo "ssh-rsa BBRdt5...LguTtp userB" >> /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: The problem of this approach is that it will concatenate the file on every deploy. The solution proposed by @rch850 doesn't have this problem.

Comment: When I copy pasted this code I get some bad chars that aren't spaces, please watch out for that

Comment: You could avoid the concatenation problem mentioned by @RobertoSchneiders by adding an additional deduping command: `command: sort -u /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys -o /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Answer (score 7):

One way you could accomplish this is to create a user data script which appends the public keys of the additional key-pairs you want to use to ~ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys, and launch the instance with that user data, for example:

```
#!
echo ssh-rsa AAAB3N...QcGskx keyname >> ~ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
echo ssh-rsa BBRdt5...LguTtp another-key >> ~ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: That's true, but it would make it more difficult to manage keys through the various AWS tools. Is there some way within AWS to do this?

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk does not allows you to specify user-data

Comment: You can use a file like `.ebextensions/app.config` in the source tree for the application version being deployed to add additional commands. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html

Answer (score 5):

## The most dynamic way to add multiple SSH keys to Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instances

### Step 1

Create a group in IAM. Call it something like `beanstalk-access`. Add the users who need SSH access to that group in IAM. Also add their public ssh key(s) to their IAM `Security credentials`.

### Step 2

The deployment script below will be parsing JSON data from AWS CLI using a handy Linux tool called `jq` ([jq official tutorial](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/)), so we need to add it in .ebextensions:

```
  packages:
    yum:
      jq: []
```

### Step 3

Add the following BASH deployment script to .ebextensions:

```
  files:
    "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/980_beanstalk_ssh.sh":
      mode: "000755"
      owner: ec2-user
      group: ec2-user
      content: |
        #!/bin/bash
        rm -f /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
        users=$(aws iam get-group --group-name beanstalk-access | jq '.["Users"] | [.[].UserName]')
        readarray -t users_array < <(jq -r '.[]' <<<"$users")
        declare -p users_array
        for i in "${users_array[@]}"
        do
        user_keys=$(aws iam list-ssh-public-keys --user-name $i)
        keys=$(echo $user_keys | jq '.["SSHPublicKeys"] | [.[].SSHPublicKeyId]')
        readarray -t keys_array < <(jq -r '.[]' <<<"$keys")
        declare -p keys_array
        for j in "${keys_array[@]}"
        do
        ssh_public_key=$(aws iam get-ssh-public-key --encoding SSH --user-name $i --ssh-public-key-id $j | jq '.["SSHPublicKey"] .SSHPublicKeyBody' | tr -d \")
        echo $ssh_public_key >> /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
        done
        done
        chmod 600 /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
        chown ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Unfortunately, because this is YAML, you can't indent the code to make it more easily readable. But let's break down what's happening:

- (In the code snippet directly below) We're removing the default SSH key file to give full control of that list to this deployment script.

  ```
    rm -f /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
  ```
- (In the code snippet directly below) Using AWS CLI, we're getting the list of users in the `beanstalk-access` group, and then we're piping that JSON list into `jq` to extract only that list of `$users.

  ```
    users=$(aws iam get-group --group-name beanstalk-access | jq '.["Users"] | [.[].UserName]')
  ```
- (In the code snippet directly below) Here, we're converting that JSON `$users` list into a BASH array and calling it `$users_array`.

  readarray -t users_array < <(jq -r '.[]' <<<"$users")
    declare -p users_array
- (In the code snippet directly below) We begin looping through the array of users.

  ```
    for i in "${users_array[@]}"
    do
  ```
- (In the code snippet directly below) This can probably be done in one line, but it's grabbing the list of SSH keys associated to each user in the `beanstalk-access` group. It has not yet turned it into a BASH array, it's still a JSON list.

  ```
    user_keys=$(aws iam list-ssh-public-keys --user-name $i)
    keys=$(echo $user_keys | jq '.["SSHPublicKeys"] | [.[].SSHPublicKeyId]')
  ```
- (In the code snippet directly below) Now it's converting that JSON list of each users' SSH keys into a BASH array.

  ```
   readarray -t keys_array < <(jq -r '.[]' <<<"$keys")
   declare -p keys_array
  ```
- (In the code snippet directly below) Now it's converting that JSON list into a BASH array.

  ```
   readarray -t keys_array < <(jq -r '.[]' <<<"$keys")
   declare -p keys_array
  ```
- (In the code snippet directly below) Now we loop through each user's array of SSH keys.

  ```
   for j in "${keys_array[@]}"
   do
  ```
- (In the code snippet directly below) We're adding each SSH key for each user to the `authorized_keys` file.

  ```
  ssh_public_key=$(aws iam get-ssh-public-key --encoding SSH --user-name $i --ssh-public-key-id $j | jq '.["SSHPublicKey"] .SSHPublicKeyBody' | tr -d \")
  echo $ssh_public_key >> /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
  ```
- (In the code snippet directly below) Close out both the `$users_array` loop and `$users_keys` loop.

  ```
  done
  done
  ```
- (In the code snippet directly below) Give the `authorized_keys` file the same permissions it originally had.

  ```
  chmod 600 /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
  chown ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
  ```

### Step 4

If your Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance is in a public subnet, you can just ssh into it using:

`ssh ec2-user@ip-address -i /path/to/private/key`

If your Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance is in a private subnet (as it should be for cloud security best practices), then you will need to have a "bastion server" EC2 instance which will act as the gateway for tunneling all SSH access to EC2 instances. Look up `ssh agent forwarding` or `ssh proxy commands` to get an idea of how to accomplish SSH tunneling.

### Adding new users

All you do is add them to your IAM `beanstalk-access` group and run a deployment, and that script will add them to your Elastic Beanstalk instances.

Comment: This fails for me due to and aws iam command: 2018-10-16 13:43:24    ERROR   [Instance: i-05cc43b96ffc69145] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...rform: iam:GetGroup on resource: group beanstalk-access

Comment: @JosephCrawford Are you sure you created the IAM group called `beanstalk-access`? Then also make sure there are users assigned to that group.

Comment: Yes I did both of those but that is the error returned from beanstalk during a deploy.  Also I removed the config file and removed jq from the yum packages and now I still cannot deploy as it is trying to run that command with every deploy which I found to be very odd.

Comment: ls -la .ebextensions
total 16
drwxrwxrwx@  4 jcrawford  staff   128 Oct 16 15:03 .
drwxrwxrwx@ 36 jcrawford  staff  1152 Oct 16 09:18 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 jcrawford  staff   744 Sep 18 10:07 composer.config
-rw-r--r--@  1 jcrawford  staff    73 Oct 16 09:53 project.config

2018-10-16 19:05:05    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2018-10-16 19:06:09    ERROR   [Instance: i-05cc43b96ffc69145] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...erform: iam:GetGroup on resource: group BeanstalkAccess

Comment: Finally was able to get our environment back into a running state.  Will clone our QA environment upon further testing of enabling SSH.

Answer (score 2):

instead of running `echo` and storing your keys on Git, you can upload your public keys to IAM user's on AWS and than do:

```
commands:
  copy_ssh_key_userA: 
    command: rm -f /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys;aws iam list-users --query "Users[].[UserName]" --output text | while read User; do aws iam list-ssh-public-keys --user-name "$User" --query "SSHPublicKeys[?Status == 'Active'].[SSHPublicKeyId]" --output text | while read KeyId; do aws iam get-ssh-public-key --user-name "$User" --ssh-public-key-id "$KeyId" --encoding SSH --query "SSHPublicKey.SSHPublicKeyBody" --output text >> /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys; done; done;
```