# AWS EC2 .pem certificate when creating with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've setup new application with *Elastic Beanstalk* as guided [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html).
Now I want to **access on EC2 server through ssh**. I hadn't had any key pair, so I've generated new key pair, but still getting *Permission denied (publickey).*

SSH trace:

```
$ ssh -v -i ~/.ec2/my.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-215-179-79.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/sergey/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-215-179-79.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [54.215.179.79] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/sergey/.ec2/my.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/sergey/.ec2/my.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ec2-54-215-179-79.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/sergey/.ssh/known_hosts:26
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/sergey/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/sergey/.ec2/my.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Could you please help me with what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How did you configure Elastic Beanstalk to use your key? Did you follow all the steps described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742478/ssh-to-elastic-beanstalk-instance ?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to ssh into your ec2 instance when you are using beanstalk. I suggest you to better create an instance and set up the env and deploy the code so that you will have more control over your app and also underlying OS.

Comment: have you used beanstalk before, what could you suggest? I've used it because there was good guide and it was the first result in google search response about deploying Rails on AWS.

Comment: I have used beanstalk before for ruby on rails stack. If you are looking for PaaS providers for ruby I suggest heroku then beanstalk. At any given point of time EC2 is a better option, if its a experimental project go for heroku though its also hosted on EC2