# Updating gems and aws deploy error ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My application is running fine over `Elasticbeanstalk`. as i have connected my repo with `gemnasium`, so it said about outdated gems and i updated them.
1: First i just ran the bundle update command then deployed i got error

```
Creating application version archive "app-51c4-160115_105334".
Uploading evercam-admin-live/app-51c4-160115_105334.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
ERROR: [Instance: i-40adb5c9] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...ror: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/var/app/ondeck/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/var/app/ondeck/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/app/ondeck/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace). 
container_command 01seed in .ebextensions/seed.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-40adb5c9'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.                                

ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

After searching around over `stackoverflow` i found out that updating each gem separately will be better and did the same.

Gems with no version number. i did `bundle update gemname` and for those who are with version number i updated version number in gemfile and again did the the same `bundle update gemname`
2: it updated the gem as well. and then i deployed that branch again.
and got the EXACT same error again.

anyhelp will be appreciated thanks

Comment: Like got failed when running `.ebextensions/seed.config`, could you ssh to beanstalk and manually run all commands from `.ebextensions/seed.config`. Moreover, how about the detail log in `/var/log/eb-activity.log`?

Comment: really, if can't run command `eb ssh` you can go to ec2 console and connect to it directly!

Comment: am totally new to this, i dont know to and i cant risk application in experiments, is there can be a fix locally for laod erro?

Comment: Hmm sorry usually cannot, checkout this which shows how to ssh to beanstalk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742478/ssh-to-elastic-beanstalk-instance