# AWS Elastic Beanstalk How to enable compression

Tags: amazon-web-services, compression, gzip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk application:

[image]

As you can see, I am running a Web Server on Tomcat.

After running [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) over [my website](http://www.thewhozoo.com), I see in order to improve performance I need to **Enable compression**.

I have read [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) that I need to add a `.ebextensions` folder to my root folder. Where is that?

I have tried adding it to my `webapp` folder. Is that correct?

[image]

What files do I need to add to this `.ebextensions` folder? Then do I just upload the app to AWS via the dashboard?

Apologies for being vague, but as you can tell, I am pretty clueless here.

**UPDATE**

I added this to the root:

```
.../main/webapp/.ebextensions/apache.config
```

where `apache.config`:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/gzip.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        <Location />
        # Insert filter!!!
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        </Location>
```

However, when I test it [here](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/?url=d3d3LnRoZXdob3pvby5jb20=), I get:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to compress to improve performance? Are you writing data into S3 or something which you would like to compress?

Comment: I have a static website with .svg, .png, .jpg, .css & ,html that I would like to compress for performance.

Comment: Is the `gzip.conf` file being created? YML files are very picky when it comes to whitespace, so the double-indent you have after the `content: |` line might be causing an issue.

Comment: How do I check if the `gzip.conf` is created?  (Excuse my naivety). I am ob AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I copied that `gzip.conf` from someone else's post, so I may have the wrong  characters. I will type it out to make sure.

Comment: Use `eb ssh` to log into your instance, and then see if the file is there with `ls /etc/httpd/conf.d/gzip.conf`. Also, following up on @notionquest's answer, the `apache.config` file needs to be put at the root level of your application on your *development* machine - the configuration commands are executed during the deployment, but the `apache.config` file won't actually be deployed.

Comment: I followed the advise in the following link, and now I cannot seem to access my server at all. My instance did not have a keypair, and I could access the server via its IP or url. Since I added a keypair, and now it's not accessible. Is this expected behaviour? If so, how do you host a public website on EB? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742478/ssh-to-elastic-beanstalk-instance

Comment: Hi Brian, I managed to set up ssh, and ad a look at the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`, and there is no `gzip.conf` file. Do you know what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

The root folder is `jbosswildfly` in the above case. It shouldn't be added to `webapps`.

[Refer this link for webapps using tomcat](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html)

[Bundling war file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-multiple-war-files.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but I still get: `www.thewhozoo.com is NOT Compressed`. Perhaps the problem is with my `apache.config`?

Answer (score 0):

Putting Cloudfront in front of your EB instance is also an option.

There is a checkbox in the behavior settings "Compress Objects Automatically" to enable gzip compression.