# Connecting to EC2 instance when deployed jhipster app using "jhipster aws"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jhipster, aws-ebs

I have deloyed a jhipster app on aws using `jhipster aws`. But when I am trying to connect to the EC2 Instance, it's giving following warning :

> **Warning**
>
> You may not be able to connect to this instance as ports 22 may need
>   to be open in order to be accessible. Your current security groups
>   don't have ports 22 open.
>
> Instance is not associated with a key pair This instance is not
>   associated with a key pair. Without a key pair you will need to log
>   into this instance using a valid username and password combination.

Please give some pointers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open the particular port to access ec2 instance (22 in your case)

Please refer this video.(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYEvbneAhk4)
[image: aws configure security group screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Though it did not solve my issue, but helped in removing first warning, after that I followed and got the solution, it helped me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742478/ssh-to-elastic-beanstalk-instance/50188308#50188308

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Elastic Beanstalk and for Elastic Beanstalk all you have to do is:

1) Go to the **Elastic Beanstalk area -> Configuration -> Security** .

2) And then **add a pre-existing EC2 key pair**.