# What default php extensions installed on AWS elastic beanstalk?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, php-extension

I need to know what extensions are installed on the AWS elastic beanstalk php platform by default, but amazon doesn't seem to have this information available on their documentation (besides the vague wording of saying that some extensions are installed by default).

Does anyone know where this information is available, or, if not, how I can figure it out myself?

I'm running AWS elastic beanstalk platform `PHP 7.1.32`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, I wasn't able to find any official information anywhere so I ended up just ssh-ing into the ec2 instance that elastic beanstalk creates and running the right commands to determine the default installed php extensions.

I followed this answer to ssh into the ec2 instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4921866/8137812

And then I ran `php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());"` on the ec2 instance.

This gave me the list of all the default extensions that are installed, specifically for the "PHP 7.1 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.6.1" platform that AWS provides.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => date
    [2] => libxml
    [3] => openssl
    [4] => pcre
    [5] => zlib
    [6] => filter
    [7] => hash
    [8] => pcntl
    [9] => readline
    [10] => Reflection
    [11] => SPL
    [12] => session
    [13] => standard
    [14] => bcmath
    [15] => bz2
    [16] => calendar
    [17] => ctype
    [18] => curl
    [19] => dom
    [20] => mbstring
    [21] => fileinfo
    [22] => ftp
    [23] => gd
    [24] => gettext
    [25] => iconv
    [26] => intl
    [27] => json
    [28] => exif
    [29] => mcrypt
    [30] => mysqlnd
    [31] => odbc
    [32] => PDO
    [33] => pgsql
    [34] => Phar
    [35] => posix
    [36] => shmop
    [37] => SimpleXML
    [38] => soap
    [39] => sockets
    [40] => sqlite3
    [41] => sysvmsg
    [42] => sysvsem
    [43] => sysvshm
    [44] => tokenizer
    [45] => xml
    [46] => xmlwriter
    [47] => xsl
    [48] => zip
    [49] => mysqli
    [50] => pdo_mysql
    [51] => PDO_ODBC
    [52] => pdo_pgsql
    [53] => pdo_sqlite
    [54] => wddx
    [55] => xmlreader
    [56] => xmlrpc
    [57] => apcu
    [58] => igbinary
    [59] => imagick
    [60] => memcache
    [61] => OAuth
    [62] => ssh2
    [63] => memcached
    [64] => Zend OPcache
)
```