# Access-Control-Allow-Origin cors error happening on NodeJS or Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

First at all, I have researched about the topic after writing the question, there are many similar question but I think the problem here is different:

[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - Node / Apache Port Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310394/no-access-control-allow-origin-node-apache-port-issue)

We are getting  this **Access-Control-Allow-Origin cors error** just when we send a **heavy request**:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend.*****.es/xxxxxx' from
>   origin 'https://www.testing.*******.es' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource

The rest of the request are working fine, I tried setting:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});
```

but I got the **same error**.

I am starting to think it can be related with **nginx**.

This is the architecture we are using:

- **NodeJs, Expressjs**
- Middlewares:

  const LIMIT = '100mb';
  const global = () => [
      morganMiddleware(),
      compression(),
      cors(),
      bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: LIMIT }),
      bodyParser.json({ limit: LIMIT }),
      helmet(),
  ];
- Server: **Nginx 12.14.1**
- Host in **AWS Elastic BeanStalk**

Let me know if anyone have any clue what can be happening because I do not know if it is coming from our nodejs server, or nginx. We have tested many solutions and are still checking out other options.

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: I do not get any response.

Answer (score 1):

Locate the type of Amazon Linux 2 (AL2) on your Elastic Beanstalk Dashboard:

[image: Elastic Beanstalk Platform type]

Create the following directory structure from the root directory of your App:

```
.platform/nginx/conf.d/
```

Create the following file:

```
.platform/nginx/conf.d/01_custom_ngix.conf
```

Add **client_max_body_size** and change the value on the following inside your *01_custom_ngix.conf* file you created *(the example here is 1000M = 1GB)* and make sure your AWS Instance Types is large enough t2.medium:

```
client_max_body_size 1000M;
client_body_buffer_size 100M;
...    
...    
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
```

Git Commit your changes.

Deploy your code:

```
> eb deploy
```

*options: eb deploy --verbose --debug*

Answer (score 0):

We are getting this error in our sever:

> 2020/02/20 10:56:00 [error] 2784#0: *127 client intended to send too
>   large body: 4487648 bytes, client: 172.31.3.222, server: , request:
>   "PUT /cars/drafts/f7124841-f72c-4133-b49e-d9f709b4cf4d HTTP/1.1",
>   host: "backend.xxxxx.es", referrer:
>   "https://www.testing.xxxx.es/sellcar/photos/f7124841-f72c-4133-b49e-d9f709b4cf4d"

So besides the error that appears in the front is **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** it is related with the a limit set in NGINX.

Now we just need to figure out how to access to our elastic beanstalk instance to change that variables and that is already solved.

[SSH to Elastic Beanstalk instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742478/ssh-to-elastic-beanstalk-instance)

To solve it, create a file x.config inside .ebextensions and change this variables with the next yaml file:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01-client_max_body_size.conf":
    mode: 000644
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # MODIFIED VARIABLES ADDED BY 01-client_max_body_size.conf
      client_max_body_size 12m;
      client_body_buffer_size 16k;
container_commands:
  nginx_reload:
    command: sudo service nginx reload
```

Then redeploy you environment.

Thank you very much all for your help!