# Can't SSH into EC2: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can't SSH into my EC2 instance created by Elastic Beanstalk. I went through all answers on this topic here on Stack Overflow and didn't find help, so I'm creating a new one.

I am connecting using the following command:

`ssh -i <path-to-key.pem> ec2-user@<ec2-public-ipv4-dns>`

When I do that, I get:

`ec2-user@<ec2-public-ipv4-dns> Permission denied (publickey).`

I checked the following things:

1. I am using the right key pair. It's attached to the EC2 as well as the EBS.
2. The security group attached to the EC2 has an inbound rule for the SSH port 22 from the source 0.0.0.0/0.
3. I tried also different user names like ubuntu and the other one (can't remember now). Same result. Historically it has always been ec2-user for me.

What am I missing here? Do I need to worry about IAM roles etc.? Key pair and open SSH port should be everything you need to SSH into an instance, right?

**EDIT:**

This is the verbose output:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/<USERNAME>/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-18-198-112-139.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file <KEYPAIRNAME>.pem type -1
debug1: identity file <KEYPAIRNAME>.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-18-198-112-139.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/<USERNAME>/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/<USERNAME>/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-18-198-112-139.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Be7wt5aVyxQ8j9mnjb5HL3ooQ49VJcgfJKtxKfrDjVo
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/<USERNAME>/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/<USERNAME>/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-18-198-112-139.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/<USERNAME>/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/<USERNAME>/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 18.198.112.139
debug1: Host 'ec2-18-198-112-139.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/<USERNAME>/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: <KEYPAIRNAME>.pem  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: <KEYPAIRNAME>.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:tEa4FVGQ3Bhw+PjrN88Z/1b8qPqw148Wu0gkhCgW8I8
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

Comment: Please use `ssh -vvv ...` to obtain a log and include the output in your question.

Comment: Are you using the `eb` cli? Did you try [eb ssh](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html)? Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742478/ssh-to-elastic-beanstalk-instance

Comment: Done. I tried eb ssh as well and got the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This means either two things:**

1. You are using the wrong security key or not using a security key. Please look at your EC2 instance configuration to make sure you have assigned the correct key to it.
2. You are using the wrong user. Make sure you have started an Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance, and make sure you're using the user ec2-user. This is something you specify when doing ec2-user@ (ex: ec2-user@35.180.242.162) in your SSH command or your Putty configuration.