# Issue while connecting to ec2 via ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have setup the keypair for my aws machine.

Added ssh - anywhere and icmp - anywhere inbound rules to my security groups.

I am able to ping the ec2 instance. but when I provide private key to my putty it asks for login as: .

Moment I provide my root user for my aws account or even "ec2-user" it says server **"refused our key"**

Comment: It would be `ec2-user` not `ec-user`.

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742478/ssh-to-elastic-beanstalk-instance

Comment: @MarkB My apologies. I tried ec2-user.

Comment: if i remember correctly, putty needs a ".ppk" style private key.  did you convert the key to ppk.  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/convert-pem-file-into-ppk/

Comment: "Refused our key" means it does not want to accept the keypair you have provided. Have you ever logged into this EC2 instance before? Was it launched with a keypair selected? How are you connecting to it? More information please!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to connect now. The key which I created was not associated with my instance.

I was able to associate keypair from elasticbeanstalk --> configuration --> Security.

After this I was able to login to EC2 via putty/winscp

Thanks all for providing help.