# WAR application and RDBMS for high volume transaction

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, amazon-web-services, haproxy

Can you please suggest some of the industry best practices (of the type "it depends") to deal with a WAR (web application archive) deployed into a J2EE container to connect with a RDBMS?

In the current scenario, we deploy the .war file to *an* Apache Tomcat instance that connects to a PostgreSQL data base instance. We are required to scale up both in terms of data storage and transactions (multi read-write).

It seems, we have two choices.

### Build load balancing system

First, we start with Apache Tomcat clustering as described [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html#Overview) with a short graphic (from their website) as below.

```
 DNS Round Robin
               |
         Load Balancer
          /           \
      Cluster1      Cluster2
      /     \        /     \
  Tomcat1 Tomcat2  Tomcat3 Tomcat4
```

Then, build the database cluster as described [here](http://www.postgres-xl.org/overview/) whose graphic is shown below[image].

Both clustering (Tomcat and PostgreSQL) are front-ended by [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) as shown in the graphic below.

[image]

### Use IaaS provider

Or, perhaps, just set-up the servers in AWS and let AWS manage all balancing while we just pay per use. For example, as described [here for a typical set-up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16248021/919480) and [here for AWS PostgreSQL](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/).